# When should I use "a" versus "an" in front of a word beginning with the letter h?

Tags: grammaticality, pronunciation, indefinite-articles, silent-letters

A basic grammar rule is to use *an* instead of *a* before a vowel sound. Given that *historic* is not pronounced with a silent h, I use “a historic”. Is this correct? What about *heroic*? Should be “It was a heroic act” or “It was an heroic act”?

I remember reading somewhere that the h is sometimes silent, in which case it’s *an*, and when the h is pronounced, it’s *a*. But then I also remember reading that it depends on which syllable is stressed. And I also think I read somewhere that it might differ between British and American English.

Personally, I pronounce the h, and believe that *a* is correct. I find that it sounds incorrect to use *an* and pronounce *heroic* without the h.

So how do I know when to use *a* and when to use *an* with a word beginning with the letter h? Are both acceptable or is there one that is correct?

Comment: I won't cry duplicate here, but a nearly identical question was asked about this same topic a few days ago: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an

Comment: See also [“a” or “an” for words that don't start with vowels but sound like they're starting with a vowel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/), [Use of “a” versus “an”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/), [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/), and [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/).

Comment: The concept of "correct" usage is always awkward in areas undergoing linguistic transition. *An orange* is always correct nowadays, but that "**n**" just slipped leftwards from the original Sanskrit *naranj*.

Comment: Unless you speak in an English dialect which uses *"an historian"* (in which case writing *"a historian"* is very difficult), you should use *"a historian"*.

Comment: I actually say "an historic"

Comment: Depends on how you pronounce "historical".

Comment: @HotLicks I think that maybe this a "cross-the-pond"-type of question.

Comment: @Cascabel - I wish I could find a Youtube of a movie bit from 15-20 years ago, where the wig of a deceased gentleman was described by a family member as "an hair-loom".

Comment: I never liked "an historical" because I aspirate the H so I always use "a." But I do say "an honor" since the H is silent in my dialect.

Comment: I think there is a middle ground. I pronounce the *H* in "Historical data shows..." but I believe I *say* "An historical case is...".  On the other hand I *write* "a historical" because if I stop to think about it, I pronounce the *h* in the isolated word.

Comment: To answer the question as it is formed: Use _a_ whenever you would pronounce _the_ as /ðə/ (_a dog, the dog_), and use _an_ whenever you would pronounce _the_ as /ði/ (_an apple, the apple). This has nothing to do with spelling. It's all sound. If the _h_ at the beginning is silent (because unstressed), it's followed by a vowel; if not, it's a consonant.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Indeed, you are correct.

In certain accents, *history*, *hotel*, etc. are pronounced with an *h* sound. In those accents, *a* should be used. In other accents, such as my own, it is pronounced without an *h* sound, and therefore starts with a vowel. In that accent, it would be correct for one to say *an*.

Queen Elizabeth II is one such person who could correctly say *an historic event*. President Obama is one such person who could correctly say *a historic event*.

In writing, it doesn't really matter which one is used.

Comment: I'm very curious. In which accents is the H in "history" and "hotel" not pronounced? I was very surprised when I first heard "herb" pronounced without the H, but that appears to be standard American; am I correct?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett: *herb* is from the French *erbe*, via latin *herba*.  The *h* is silent in those forms and was in the UK up until the 19th century.  The Americans, stunningly, pronounce it in a more correct fashion.  Although it grates on my ears every time I hear the American form.  In England *historic* is pronounced with the *h*, so I am confused as to why the Queen would use *an*.  Though the answer given by @nohat explains that usage with regard to the stress of the first syllable, as opposed to the vowel sound.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett - In most American dialects "herb"(pronounced without the h) refers to herbs as in cooking. "Herb" (pronounced with the h) is a nickname of for men named "Herbert"

Comment: I would say that in British English the unaspirated h is disappearing. Both my parents would say "an otel" while I would say "a hotel". I would be very surprised to hear it spoken with an unaspirated h except by old or upper class people.

Comment: The silent "h" has nothing to do with French ... that's a red herring. People said "an hereafter" in the 19th century, and the word "hereafter" comes to us from Old English ... see this [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hereafter%2C+an+hereafter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @PeterShor: The fact that people said "an hereafter" (not a French derivative) doesn't necessarily mean it has nothing to do with French. People could be overapplying a learned pattern (I guess that's a form of hypercorrection). But I would be interested in more thoughts/references about why (or according to what rules) people started using "an" before words starting with "h".

Comment: It's possible that the "an historical" form relates to the influence of ancient Greek (in which the "h" sound is indicated by a rough aspirate, not a letter) among those with classical educations.

Comment: @Orbling I, for one, am not stunned that our American pronunciation of "herb" is the more "correct".  Many aspects of our language can be explained by changes that failed to happen here.

Comment: @Orbling *Herb* without the *h* is not unique to America. Cockneys rarely pronounce the initial *h* in anything.

Comment: @WS2 Just noticed your comment. Cockneys do drop Hs like the plague, I am one who does, but we do not tend to drop it in the word herb or herbs.  Some do, rarely, but it is not the accepted pronunciation in that case (for the Cockey dialect that is), just utter laziness.

Comment: I think that "dialect" is more accurate than "accent".

Comment: @Acccumulation
While I think both "dialect" and "accent" would be correct in this case, "accent" is more focused on a how a word is pronounced (the case here), whereas "dialect" can be used to refer to a way of speaking that has completely changed grammar and vocabulary.

Answer (score 75):

The point of the word *an* is to avoid the awkward silent pause between words when saying something like "a apple." So, you should put *an* before any word that begins with a vowel **sound**, not just a vowel letter.

The good news is that you just need to do whatever makes sense when talking:

- a historian
- an honor
- a xylophone
- an X-ray
- a user (begins with *y* sound)
- an umbrella
- a one-eyed pirate (begins with *w* sound)
- an owl

Comment: +1 for the very good examples. However (in the UK) you will still hear "an hotel", "an historian" occasionally, even with the "h" still clearly spoken (though unstressed).

Comment: +1 great examples! I never really thought much about the exceptions when words begin with *o* or *u*

Comment: What was the ambiguity with 'xylophone'? 'ksylo-', 'zylo-', 'sylo-' none starts with a vovel. And I don't think pronouncing it as 'aylophone' or 'eksaylo...' would be anywhere near correct.

Comment: @SF.: Xylophone was included in the list to contrast it with X-ray (which is pronounced "ex-ray").

Comment: I come across this question because of a technical term `an HTTP request` that aroused my curiosity. It's true I always pronounce it "an h-t-t-p".

Answer (score 36):

It is a traditional rule of English that *an* can be used before words that begin with an H sound if the first syllable of that word is not stressed. Indeed, some traditionalists would say it must be used before such words. Since the first syllable of *historic* is unstressed, it is acceptable to use *an* before it.

In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/), there are 1591 incidences of “a historic” and 428 incidences of “an historic”, showing that usage of *an* before such words is dying out.

Comment: How did this rule come about? Why do we even have different words for "a" and "an"?

Comment: The rule probably came about because H as the onset of unstressed syllables is often very lightly or not pronounced at all, making the syllable just like a vowel-initial syllable, making the word a candidate for *an* treatment. Having separate words for *a* and *an* I discussed about in another question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an/164

The

Comment: If you enable sections for your query you get even better evidence for your claim that 'an history' is dying out.  With sections enabled you can see the trend from 1990 to today.  The ration of a:an goes from about 3:1 in 1990 to 5:1 today.  At least in AmE.  A similar query at BNC gives different results.

Comment: The number of incidences in the Corpus you have cited says nothing about whether the "an" usage is dying out, increasing, or staying the same.  Simply that it is less common than the "a" usage.  I liked your first paragraph though!

Comment: This linguistics post may be relevant: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/15716/5581 You can also see the effect of stress on "h" in the traditional pronunciation of words like "vehicle" (no h sound) vs."vehicular" (with an h sound).

Comment: @VincentMcNabb disregarding the debate about h- words, I'd say "an" just flows more naturally into words beginning with a vowel.  Hungarian has the exact same thing with a/az, their word for "the": "a narancs", "az alma"

Comment: @Chris the first syllable in "history" is stressed, so it wouldn't be a candidate for use with an anyway.

Answer (score 17):

Holy Moly (Or Oly Moly):

[Google books ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20historic%2Ca%20historic%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20historic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20historic%3B%2Cc0) for "a historic" and "an historic"

[image: an historic,a historic]

Comment: This made me laugh, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: That really is *Holy Moly* :-)

Comment: 1940 was an historic moment for these two forms.

Comment: So 'an historic' is a historic pronunciation.

Answer (score 10):

In words beginning with “h” where the accent is on the 2nd syllable, it is also correct to use "an".  In such cases you do not pronounce the “h”.

So "an historical act" is spoken as "an'istorical act".

This practice has a long, respected pedigree, at least in British literature.

Comment: Fowler mentions this too. But does it apply equally to all kinds of such words? For some reason I suspect it is more common with "historical" than with some other words without stress on the first syllable. Doesn't the length of the word have something to do with it?

Comment: I agree with your first sentence but disagree with the second. I would say "an historical", "an heroic", "an hotel" etc, with 'h' pronounced.

Comment: There is ample evidence for 'an hotel' as well.  But like any of the "an = h*" uses, they re more prevalent in British English as compared to American English, and were more common in the 19th century than today.

Comment: @chimp where do you live?  Is that common there?

Comment: I think this answer reflects the true situation (though ignores trends). But an answer on ELU (at least nowadays) is considered inadequate if not backed by authoritative reference/s.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty hard to decide who is "correct". I can offer the example of someone like newsreader Jeremy Paxman who decidedly says "an historic" with an aspirated "h". There are also lots more television announcers who do this in the UK. It strikes me as being an example of hypercorrectness similar to blanket-removal of linking-r sounds.

Comment: I too hear this a lot particularly on BBC Radio 4.  It irritates me immensely for some reason!  Surely either "a historic" or "an 'istoric" if you want to sound Frenchified?!

Answer (score 3):

You ask why some people say or write *an historical*. The thing is, that's not what any people actually say or write. People who use the string *an historical* is going have a noun after it. E.g, *novel*:

- *He started **an historical novel** today and now he can't put it down.*

because *an historical* is not a complete constituent; it has to have a noun to modify. But *an historical novel* **is** a complete constituent. And in that constituent, you will notice that the stress is on the syllable with **TOR** in it.

- *an hisTORical novel*

And you will also notice that the syllable with *his* in it is not stressed, and that there is a strong tendency to leave out the /h/ when saying it, producing something that might be pronounced

- **/ənɪ'storəkəl'navəl/**,

and might be spelled

- *an 'istorical novel*

if one had the simple faith in apostrophes that millions display daily.

A linguist would say (and this linguist does say) that initial /h/ is frequently dropped before unstressed syllables. Stressed initial syllables are more normal in English than unstressed, and so they don't drop /h/; these include all monosyllables like *ham* and *hint*, for instance.

This is not a rule that has to be followed; this is an **optional** rule that is followed by many people, but not by all, often, but not always, even by the same people. So sometimes people **say** "an historical", because *'istorical* starts with a vowel in speech, and the rule says *an* before vowels when they're pronounced as vowels in speech, never mind spelling. So in those cases they'll write it *an historical*, too, because it's a speech rule, not a spelling rule.

Comment: Let’s give ’er another chestnut to gnaw on: this also sometimes happens with *an hypnotic state* or *an hypnotic trance* or *an hypnotic drug,* and for the same reason you cite. Here’s a bit of regulatory legalese from 1955 that does this: *“Every person who furnishes any hypnotic drug to any other person shall first obtain from  the board **an hypnotic license** for each separate office, shop, store or other place of business, which license shall expire on the thirty-first day of October and shall be annually renewed.”*

Answer (score 2):

See this question/answer: [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)

> The question of "a" vs "an" is always decided by the pronunciation of the word that follows the article. Thus, various geographical regions that have different pronunciation rules may use a different article for the same word."

In short, if you pronounce the "h" then use "a". If you do not pronounce the "h", use "an."

Comment: I suppose the question might be whether to pronounce the h.

Comment: @Cerberus: Upon re-reading it, I think you are right. As worded, it's ambiguous.

Comment: True. I think JYelton wasn't aware of the mechanism and thus did not know what he wanted to ask exactly.

Comment: See Master of Disaster's comment: in UK spoken English there are a reasonable number of people who say "an hotel" etc with a clear (though unstressed) h, so this isn't a 100% solid rule.

Answer (score 1):

I use "an" before a word which I think would start with a vowel in the speech of whoever I'm talking to.  For instance, I ordinarily say "an" before "historical", because although I always pronounce "h" at the beginning of "historical", I believe that many people don't pronounce an "h" here.  I just want to get along.

Answer (score 0):

If you pronounce the h, say *a historian*. If you don't pronounce the h, say *an historian*. The latter sounds old-fashioned now.

Comment: But what if you pronounce the "h" after vowels, but not after consonants? (This is what I do.)

Comment: Then pronounce it either way. People differ. _Historian_, with unstressed initial syllable, is one where I can swing both ways, too.

Comment: @PeterShor You pronounce teeth as teet?

Comment: Sometime do, sometimes don't. It depends what mood I'm in, and whether 'an' seems to roll off the tongue more easily in the context. Now I know it is old fashioned I am likely to use it more often, since it suits my appearance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In contemporary usage, if the "H" is voiced, as in "house" or "happy", the article "a"is becoming more common, for example, "He is a humble man". if the "H" is not voiced, as in "honest", or "honorable", an is still generally preferred.

In older texts, it is more common to have "an" in places where contemporary usage favors "a". Psalm 84:3 (Protestant versification) talks about the sparrow finding "an house" in the Jewish temple.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of article is based on pronunciation, not spelling, so for instance "an honor". There are some dialects in which the h in "historical" is silent, and for those dialects, "an historical" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A balanced overview to be found posted on [Writing Skills](https://www.writing-skills.com/hit-or-myth-use-an-before-h-words) [slightly reformatted and amended]:

> **Hit or myth? Use ‘an’ before h-words**
>
> Author : Catie Holdridge Posted: 26/11/2011
>
> No one ever said English was a straightforward language. No sooner
> have you learned one rule than you are presented with all the
> exceptions. As dewy-eyed innocents, we were taught to put *a* before
> words beginning with consonants and *an* before those starting with
> vowels, only then to hear that the rule bends a bit before h-words.
>
> Or does it?
>
> OK, so sense dictates that we give words where the initial *h* is
> silent an honorary place with the vowel words (along with some
> abbreviations). But what of those people who still insist on putting
> *an* before such words as *historical, hysterical, heroic, horrific* and *hotel* – are they just horribly old-fashioned?
>
> Does Jack Nicholson’s Johnny go mad in *a hotel* or *an hotel*? Is it
> *a horrific* film or *an horrific* film?
>
> > *How does it sound?*
> >
> > It all comes down to pronunciation. There are some h-words no one
> > would ever dream of putting *an* before, like *horrible, happy,
> > hospital* or *home*.
> >
> > But while you might use *an* before *historical*, you wouldn’t before
> > *history*. Similarly, you may before *habitual* but would never before
> > *habit*. So, what the heck?
> >
> > It comes down to which syllable of the word is stressed. Try saying
> > these words aloud and you’ll find that for those where you land more
> > heavily on the first syllable, you fully pronounce (aspirate) the *h*.
> > For these you would automatically use *a*. But where the first
> > syllable is unaccented, the *h* tends to soften, or is lost
> > altogether, making *an* seem natural – **at least to some ears**....
>
> *An on the wane*
>
> ... **But** support for this *an* is on the wane. Both the Guardian and
> Telegraph style guides, as well as the Oxford Dictionary, advocate
> using *a* when the *h* is pronounced **at all** (‘*a hotel, a
> historian*, [*a history*]’). And etymologist Michael Quinion, himself a
> self-confessed ‘old-fashioned’ *an* user, points out younger people’s
> preference for *a*.
>
> *However*, fogies with a fondness for *an* can at least still count on The
> Times style guide (‘prefer *an hotel* to *a hotel*, *an historic* to
> *a historic*, *an heroic* rather than *a heroic*’).
>
> And Fowler’s Modern English Usage kindly acknowledges that ‘the choice
> of form remains open’.
>
> Verdict: A half hit (halmost) Like the last drinker in the pub at
> closing time, this half-rule appears always on the verge of leaving
> and yet continues to hang on. Use the *an+h form* [in those examples where traditionalists cling on to it] if you wish, but
> know that you run the risk of appearing dated. And if you have an
> international readership, be warned: there’s little to no support for
> this habit in American English.
>
> Let’s give the last word to Fowler’s: ‘[S]peakers who like to say *an*
> should not try to have it both ways by aspirating the h.’ So just know
> that you can’t have your *an+h* and aspirate it too. Hain’t it always
> the way?

Answer (score -1):

My rule of thumb (which I can't prove/cite, but which I'm sure is correct) is to use an for any word that *sounds* like it begins with a vowel. Both "a history" and "a historian" begin with an H sound. If you slur it into 'istorian, then I would use "an" in spoken sentences (but as that's an incorrect pronunciation anyway you should definitely write it as "a historian."