# When to use 'an' and when to use 'a' with words begining with 'h'?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Some h-words need 'an' for the indefinite article (I will be there in an hour).

Other h-words need 'a' for the indefinite article (It is a history of sadness).

Is there a general rule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "a" versus "an" in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)

Answer (score 19):

If the "h" is pronounced, use "a". If it is silent, use "an".

This is in keeping with the general rule, which is to use "an" for words beginning with a vowel sound.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely a matter of vowel sound, and has nothing to do with what the first *letter* is: we'd say "a European" and "a university" because those words don't begin with vowel sounds.

Answer (score 12):

If a word begins with a vowel *sound*, then the indefinite article to use is *an*. If a word begins with a consonant *sound*, then the indefinite article to use is *a*.

There is a singular exception: If a word begins with an H sound **and** the first syllable of the word is unstressed, then you can use either *an* or *a*. Traditional rules says you must use *an*, but there is so much ignorance of this exception that you will find *a* is much more common in this case. For example, in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, there are 1956 incidences of *a historical* but only 415 incidences of *an historical*. However, using *an* here is also unimpeachably correct.

Comment: @nohat: to me, an historical sounds completely wrong, and I always assumed it was a British English thing, because they don't pronounce the Hs on some words where Canadians and Americans do. What is the basis for the an here if not the silent H?

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: really?  What words are you thinking of?  I can’t think of any like that, but there are several in the other direction: some widespread US dialects (northeastern/midwestern?) pronounce eg “herb”, “human”, “humour” without the “h”, whereas in the UK this only occurs in some deep rural dialects, afaik.  See Eddie Izzard’s prescriptivist but wonderful rant against American pronunciation: “It’s ‘herbs’.  *Because there’s a fucking h in it!”*

Comment: "an hour and a half" sounds like a very clear example of the rule.

Comment: @PLL: Your experience is completely opposite from mine.  I've never heard an American say `'uman` but I've heard (on movies, TV, etc) lots of UK spears say things like `"I've 'eard the 'overcraft was full of 'umans".`

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: oh, of course, you’re absolutely right about that English h-dropping — I was completely forgetting that!  Yes, that’s well-attested and I think still common in plenty of dialects; North London is where I’ve heard it most myself.  The American h-dropping I know is much narrower: afaik it would never include *’eard*, only *yumans*, *yuge* etc. (i.e. word-initial /hju/ -> /ju/), plus a few specific isolated examples like *’erbs*.  The speakers I met it in were middle-class and well-educated, from urban Pennsylvania/Ohio/New Jersey (which may just reflect that I lived in Pittsburgh).

Comment: @Mr. Shiney: I usually say "an 'istorical moment" (American English), myself.

Comment: This gets a bit tricky when using acronyms. It would be "an H-bomb", but "a hydrogen bomb", for example.

Comment: @Wayne, “H-bomb” doesn't begin with an H sound, does it? It begins with a vowel sound, so it uses *an*.

Comment: @nohat: yes, I realize that of course. I'm just saying that what might be perceived as the same word (though abbreviated) can differ because the abbreviation is pronounced differently. And it can differ on the fly if you decide to expand the acronym as you read it, for example when reading a report aloud.

Answer (score 1):

With some words it has to do with the French connection. The French don't pronounce hard 'H's. So words like Herbal are pronounced 'erbal, leading to a glottal stop if 'a' is used. That's why historically words like hospital and hotel have used 'an'. Written English would therefore use 'an'. In spoken English it depends entirely on whether or not you pronounce the 'H'.