# Pronunciation of "the"

Tags: definite-articles, pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the pronunciation of “the”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the)

I've noticed that the word *the* is not always pronounced in the same way depending on the sound of the next word. I think it may be like the word *a/an*:

- *an* for words starting with a vowel sound: e.g. owl, honest person
- *a* for words starting with a consonant sound: e.g. dog, user

Is there any rule for this? What would be the exact sound for each case (please give a similar word with the same sound to have an idea)?

Comment: @RegDwight If it is closed as exact duplicate, could you indicate a link to the similar question asked before? I've searched before and I haven't found it.

Comment: The link is at the very top of your question, where it says “Possible Duplicate: [What is the pronunciation of 'the'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the)”. I know it's not immediately obvious due to being formatted as a quote. There's a [bug report](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/662/) on meta.

Comment: @RegDwight OK, thank you very much and sorry for the duplicate question.