# Usage of the definite articles with personal names

Tags: names, definite-articles

Could you tell me if the following sentence is correct or not? It seems to me that it is not correct because as I know, definite articles are never used with personal names. The only thing that I worry about is that I found this sentence on a website for learning English.

> That evening, jack saw **the** Maria and Angela. They looked hungry so he offered them a hot meal.

Source pdf: http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cathyp/eBooks/LearningEnglish/EnglishTown/Unit%20overview%20-%20Level%207%20Unit%204.pdf

Comment: A related question, from Linguistics.SE: [Articles before the name of a person](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/articles-before-the-name-of-a-person)

Comment: I wouldn't trust a site that doesn't even care about *capitalizing* the name *Jack*.

Comment: Two words: **The Donald**.

Comment: Somewhat related: [The pronunciation of “the”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1082/2085).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [voxanimus noted](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51319/2085), that use is incorrect.

The only correct use I can think of that works that way is when speaking of a well-known individual.

For example, in this exchange:

> Dennis Ritchie is dead.
>
> Not *the* Dennis Ritchie?  dmr?  The guy who developed C?

That instance of *the* would be emphasized so that it would be pronounced just like the pronoun *thee*, so /ðiː/ with a long, drawn-out vowel.

Comment: Yes.  And you could make up a scenario where this usage would make sense in: "Jack saw *the* Maria and Angela."

Answer (score 5):

No. That sentence is wrong.

Unless the Maria and Angela are works of art (or other inanimate, named objects like museums) that consume food.

Answer (score 4):

If Maria and Angela are people, *the* would not normally be found in front of their names. It might help us understand why the website uses this example if you could provide a link to it.

Although personal names are not normally found with the definite article, there are exceptions when the name is preceded by an adjective or postmodified by a relative clause and in the case that Wudang illustrates.

Comment: I added a link to the source, but it doesn't help much.

Comment: @Hugo: No, it doesn't. The organization behind it seems a fairly serious one, so the insertion of 'the', and the small letter in 'jack' may have been an oversight. If so, they should be more careful.