# Why it is "the Grinch" but not just Grinch as it's his personal name?

Tags: definite-articles, names, proper-nouns, north-american-english

We don't use the definite article with personal names, however, in "the Grinch", why is it so?

Yeah, I know sometimes we can use "the". When it's a person everybody knows about or something like that.

But I wonder why it's "the Grinch"?

Comment: How do you know that Grinch is his personal name? We say *the President, the King, the High Chancellor, the Devil, the Pope, the Leviathan, the Loch Ness Monster, the Abominable Snowman*. None of these are personal names.

Comment: Paula, wel­come to Stack Ex­change! Thanks for post­ing this as a new ques­tion [af­ter we asked you to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51318/usage-of-the-definite-articles-with-personal-names#comment1157615_479498).  ¶ **AT­TEN­TION WOULD-BE CLO­SERS**: Please do not close this ques­tion.The asker had ac­ci­den­tally posted it as an an­swer to [Usage of def­i­nite ar­ti­cles with per­sonal names](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51318/2085), then fol­lowed our ad­vice. So please don't close this off-hand­edly; in­stead, ***edit* it to im­prove it** if you can.

Comment: There is a guy who goes by the name "The Donald", but I can't remember what happened to him...

Comment: @jimm101 He was governor of Maryland in the late 1980's and early 1990's and then he was comptroller, and passed away in 2011. I've heard rumors about some poser from New York but they're hard to credit.

Answer (score 8):

The Grinch is not his name. Although it’s not shown in *The Grinch*, “Grinch” is the name of whatever beast the Grinch is. Were he something else, we might call him the Sasquatch.

But other Grinches are featured in other stories. According to *[The Hoobub and the Grinch](https://forestsociety.org/blog-post/hoobub-and-grinch)*:

> Grinches sell Hoobubs such things [e.g. a worthless piece of string] each day.

[image: Full poem with picture of an orange Grinch offering a Hoobub a string]

Also, both "Mr. [Animal]" and "the [Animal]" are commonly used in stories, such as this version  of [The Tortoise and the Hare](https://www.shortstoriesforkids.net/stories-for-kids/the-tortoise-and-the-hare/):

> “Good morning, Mr. Hare,” the Tortoise said.

Comment: If *Grinch* is the name of the species, then why is it capitalised? It is the combination of the definite article and the capitalisation that is troubling the OP. And if *Grinch* is not his surname, why is he referred to as *Mr. Grinch*?

Comment: There are lots of Mr Hedgehog, Mr Wolf, Mr Frog etc in children's literature. It is a common form of address for animals by children, such as the children's game [What's the time, Mr Wolf?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_the_time,_Mr_Wolf%3F), Roald Dahl's Fantastic Mr Fox, [Mr Beaver](https://narnia.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Beaver) in the Chronicles of Narnia, etc.

Comment: I don't recall seeing the Grinch referred to in Dr. Seuss's original book as "Mr. Grinch." The place where that term is used (repeatedly) is in the song "You're a Mean One, Mr. Grinch," which appears in the television adaptation but not in the book. As for capitalizing the G in "the Grinch," Dr. Seuss consistently initial-caps the names of his many made-up creatures, such as the Tizzle-Top-Tufted Mazurka (from _If I Ran the Zoo_), the Fibbel (from _If I Ran the Circus_), the Yink (from _One Fish Two Fish Red Fish Blue Fish_), and the Smorgasbord (from _Happy Birthday to You_).