# What is the origin of several pronunciations of "the"?

Tags: pronunciation, articles, pronunciation-vs-spelling, weak-forms

Courtesy links: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123348/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the

[What is the pronunciation of "the"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the)

> *The* has two pronunciations: "thuh" /ðə/  and "thee" /ði/. While in a few dialects the rules are less well-defined, in most British and American dialects you say "thuh" when it precedes a consonant sound.
>
> - **The(thuh) person** /ðə pɜ:sən/
> - **The(thuh) university** /ðə ju:nɪvɜ:sɪti/
>
> But you say "thee" when it precedes a vowel.
>
> - **The(thee) apple** /ði æpl/
> - **The(thee) imagination**  /ði ɪmædʒɪneɪʃn/
>
> Note that "University" is pronounced "Yuniversity", which is started with a consonant sound.
>
> The definite article ‘*the*’ is normally pronounced `/ðə/` before a consonant sound and `/ði/` before a vowel sound.   Neither of these is a stressed syllable.
>
> However, it also has a ‘stressed’ pronunciation used for emphasis, which is always `/ðiː/` no matter what sound should follow it. The vowel here is held longer than in the unstressed version.

The answers above tell when to pronounce "the" as what, but I am curious to know about how English ended up getting multiple pronunciations for "the"?

Comment: [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/the) has some information on the history of "the", which like many common words is rather complex: it comes from OE *þæt* (that), influenced by many other, older definite articles, and there's a long history of distinct forms before vowels. You could try the OED for more detailed info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Weak Forms vs Strong Forms

*The* is not special in this regard, and it has no unique pronunciation history of its own. You just have to know when to use its **weak form** and when to use its **strong form**, something we see all over English with many, many other words like this.

The Wikipedia article mentioned in the references given at the end of this post contrasts *to Cambridge* before a consonant yielding /tə/ with a reduced vowel with *to Oxford* before a vowel yielding /tu/ with an unreduced one. You get the same thing happening with *the* when especially stressed or before a vowel. This shows it is a general phenomenon not one peculiar to *the*.

#### The definite article *the* is no different from many other monosyllabic function words.

Content words take prosodic stress in English, but grammatical words usually do not. These common function words are subject to “reduced pronunciations” whenever they occur in unstressed positions. This phenomenon is not unique to English; for example, weak forms also occur in neighboring Dutch.

Many one-syllable function words in English have phonemically distinct
**weak forms** found in unstressed contexts that contrast with their more
fully pronounced strong forms. Weak forms have reduced vowels (usually
**schwa**) and sometimes reduced consonants as well. Not all dialects and
speakers have the same set of weak forms, and further constraints on where
weak forms appear may apply to some of these.

Examples of function words with weak forms include *a, an, and, be, been, but, he, her, him, his, just, me, or, she, than, that* (as conjunction), *the, them, us, we, who, you, your*. Weak forms can also be found in some utterances of *as, at, for, from, of, to, some, there* in some contexts for some speakers, as well as in *are, can, could, do, does, had, has, have, my, must, shall, should, was, were, will, would*.

What you see happening with the **definite** article is the same thing that you
see happening with the **indefinite** article, which is also always weak
unless emphasized.

1. Would you care to try a berry?

Only the content words in (1) are unreduced: *care*, *try*, and *berry*. That
leaves you with only /jə/ for *you*, /tə/ for *to*, etc.

But when stressed for emphasis, the indefinite pronoun *a* is now pronounced /eɪ/:

2. I guess I can try **a** berry, but just one, please.

Before a vowel, of course, *a* becomes *an*. There aren’t many other
function words that end in vowels, but *the* is one that does so, and *to*
is another. The reduction to schwa that normally happens before a consonant
is less apt to occur before a vowel. So while (3) would have weak forms
for *to* and *the*:

3. Try to sleep in the bed.

Here in (4) before the vowels those two words won’t be reduced, or **as** reduced, for most speakers:

4. Try to eat the apple.

Think of how when we say *You don’t have to shout*, the word *to* is reduced to /tə/, and the word *have* devoices its final consonant. These are the same phenomenon at work that you see with *the* in unstressed positions and before consonants.

### References

- The section on “Weak and strong forms of words” in the Wikipedia article on [Stress and vowel reduction in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Weak_and_strong_forms_of_words).
- Geoff Lindsey’s Youtube videos about the pronunciation and prosodic rhythms of weak forms: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfCsiF80TX0), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaXYas58_kc).