# Right pronunciation of 'the east'?

Tags: pronunciation

What should be the right pronunciation of 'the east'- is it 'di east' or 'da east'??

Comment: Why do you think it should be either of those options?

Comment: I saw that in some YouTube videos. I know that 'di' is pronounced before vowels & 'da' is used after consonants. But Google pronounced that as 'da east' . I think that should be 'di east'??

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596849/what-is-the-origin-of-several-pronunciations-of-the) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-the), both questions about pronouncing "the" in different contexts. It depends not only on the following sound, but on stress. This question is too vague to answer as it stands, but is probably covered by another article.

Comment: Can't I say 'the yeast'? The 'right pronunciation' is whatever is commonly spoken in a region.

Comment: Please write this in IPA and specify the region/accent in question.

Comment: Did you perhaps confuse 'D' with 'Ð' (uppercase edh)?

Comment: [ðɨ'yist] is where the Sun rises. (after it's been covered with a damp towel)