# an SQA or a SQA?

Tags: articles, abbreviations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Although I am clear about the usage of 'an' and 'a' on most cases, but I am not sure how they are applied in front abbreviations. I heard that, whether vowel or consonants, abbreviations are always used with the 'an' article.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: If you are using a TLA that starts with a consonant sound, you should use 'a'. If the ABR begins with a vowel, it's an ABR. This does lead to some small difficulty in your case because it depends on how it is habitually pronounced. If you spell it out, it should be an S-Q-A. But if you call it a SKWA, then it would be a SKWA. Sometimes both possibilities exist: an SQL script, or a SQL script, depending on whether you say ess-kew-ell, sequel or squeal. I've no idea what to do then.