# "An SQL Server database schema" or "a SQL Server database schema"?

Tags: orthography, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

I got the following sentence from the book I'm reading:

> You can take a database-first approach
>   by first creating a SQL Server
>   database schema.

From what I learned, I think it should be "**an** SQL Server database schema", not "**a** SQL Server database schema". So which one is correct?

Comment: Duplicate of [“an SQA or a SQA?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2736/), which is itself a duplicate of [“Do you use 'a' or 'an' before acronyms?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1016/)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I should have searched before asking.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify this as a duplicate, because in this case there are two different pronunciations of the acronym.  Though it is definitely very closely related, and linking to the other answers is still helpful.

Comment: Microsoft Style Guide says: Use "an SQL" (an es-cue-el) if you mean SQL the language and "a SQL" (a sequel) if you mean the product Microsoft SQL Server. For example, "an SQL database" but "a SQL Server installation".

Comment: The duplicate doesn't seem very duplicate-y to me, honestly. This is really about the fact that you can pronounce SQL as S-Q-L or as Sequel. From there, you can use the "duplicate", but on its own, it's really not enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends, I would think, on your pronunciation of *SQL*. It [can be pronounced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) as "sequel", or spelled out as "S-Q-L". That perhaps doesn't help in written English.

A [thoroughly scientific survey of Google](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22a+sql%22&word2=%22an+sql%22) throws up many more hits for "an SQL" than "a SQL". This is also the form used on that Wikipedia article and elsewhere, such as [this Microsoft SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936677%28SQL.80%29.aspx) entitled "Executing an SQL Query".

Comment: I never knew SQL can be pronounced as "sequel".

Comment: @Hai Minh Nguyen: I think there was a very early SQL product actually named "SEQUEL" and some people just use that for pronouncing SQL.

Comment: You can also pronounce it "SQUEAL," if you're a nincompoop like me.

Comment: The link to the "Google fight" these days shows many more hits for "a SQL" than "an SQL."

Comment: Either way, Google Search doesn't work very well as a corpus.  Google has never tried to make its result estimates particularly accurate.

Comment: Maybe not a corpus, but as a way to determine what is common usage, google trends certainly would argue for "a SQL": https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=%22a%20sql%22,%22an%20sql%22

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer result [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+SQL%2Can+SQL&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20SQL%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20SQL%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20SQL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Can%20SQL%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20SQL%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAn%20SQL%3B%2Cc0) shows `a SQL` as more frequent.