# Correct plural of FAQ

Tags: grammatical-number, initialisms

FAQ stands for 'Frequently asked questions', with the plural being implicit in the acronym FAQ. But it is common to see the word 'FAQs' being used, which treat the word FAQ as an object in itself, and an s being added to its end in order to pluralize it.

Which one is the correct usage for FAQ ?

Comment: Why can only one of them be correct?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the acronym does indeed stand for *Frequently Asked Questions*, in many cases, there is an implied *list of* (or perhaps *document containing*) in the acronym's usage, which is why it's treated as a singular object.  For example, I could have a FAQ that covers home buying and a separate one that has questions regarding home purchasing.  In this case, I might suggest that you check out *the FAQs*, meaning *The lists of frequently asked questions*.

In this case, I see nothing wrong with adding an *s* to pluralize the implied list (making it clear there there are multiple sets).

However, I would suggest that if you have a single list, and the *s* merely refers to the fact that multiple questions exist, the *s* is not needed.

Comment: Hmm... a set of FAQ entities can be called as FAQs.

Comment: I suppose that the _home purchasing FAQ_ is a bit more upscale than the _home buying FAQ_.  (Or is it that the former is for those of Romantic inclination, and the latter for the Germanic?)

Comment: @mgkrebbs Ha! I intended buying/selling.  Fail.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that FAQ always stands for *Frequently Asked Question**s***; a single question that is frequently asked is also a **f**requently **a**sked **q**uestion, or FAQ. Thus, a list of such questions is a list of FAQs.

Answer (score 1):

A FAQ is a collection of Frequently Asked Question(s) for a specific topic.

FAQs are a collection of multiple lists of FAQ.

“I looked up a Fallout4 FAQ on GameFAQs”

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO "FAQs" is more natural. Consider if a page referred you to their FAQ. You (I) might think "What? Only one FAQ?". So adding the "s" makes sense to me.

Also, being pedantic, FAQ is not an acronym: It is an initialism. Acronyms are pronounceable words comprised of a set of initial letters, such as the word "laser".

G

Comment: FAQ is pronounced "fack" in my idiolect, making it an acronym.

Comment: @AndyT well I say eff-ay-kew, so it can be both :)

Comment: If we're going to be pedantic, maybe rethink "comprised of".

Comment: There's actually a StackExchange thread partly about whether FAQ is pronounced as a word or initials (and whether to use "a FAQ" or "an FAQ") https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms