# Acronyms and initialisms: "a" vs "an"

Tags: word-choice, articles, acronyms, initialisms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

When there is an acronym such as NSFW (Not Safe For Work) as in the following example

> This is an NSFW link
>
> This is a Not Safe For Work link

Is it correct to use "a" or "an" when using the acronym? I've assumed that it was dependant upon how you're going to pronounce the acronym when speaking (spelling it out "N-S-F-W" or just saying what the letters stand for "Not Safe For Work"). I see in print

> This is a NSFW link

which to me is incorrect because I pronounce the acronym letters.

Comment: The difference between this and X-ray is that you never say X-ray in a way where it starts with a consonant. Many people familiar with the acronym will pronounce, "not safe for work" causing it to necessitate the use of "a" instead of "an".

Comment: A better duplicate link is: [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Comment: @MrHen good point. I have updated the question thus