# Which article would be correct in this instance?

Tags: articles, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

What article should be used directly in front of an acronym that begins with 'N?' Since the pronunciation of the letter 'N' begins with a vowel sound, would 'an' be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question and it was closed. The consensus here seems to be "do whatever you want"; I use the article corresponding to saying the English-language, expanded version, so that people who read it most properly won't complain.

Comment: But an acronym really means a *pronounceable* abbreviation, so *that* pronunciation should determine the article used. For example, it should be 'a laser'. I think people would be more likely to complain if you said 'an L A S E R'.

Comment: Except the first word is "light", so your and my method happen to agree on "a" here.

Comment: Ah, this is what you meant by expanded version -- I see. But I stand by the idea that the pronunciation of the acronym is what decides the article. An *abbreviation* like LCD is another matter because it's unpronounceable as an English word, therefore *not* an acronym.