# Should I use `a SSTP` or `an SSTP`?

Tags: word-choice, articles, abbreviations, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

First of all let me clarify that *SSTP* is an abbreviation of a technical term.
I want to know, when using in a sentence, should I use *a* or *an* before *SSTP* and such terms?

If I'm right when letter *s* is at the beginning of an actual word, it is a consonant. But what about the abbreviations?