# Using 'an' before a consonant

Tags: vowels, consonants

Depending on the word, using `an` before a consonant is not right.

What about in this phrase, "David has just gotten an SX250". To me, it does sound a lot better than "David has just gotten a SX250".

I saw a similar phrase in a book the other day, and it did not sound/look right at all!

Don't know if I'm going crazy or what..

Comment: "SX250" begins with a *vowel*. This question is a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43794/) of a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14429/) of a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5265/) of a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2736/). The original is [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1016/), and we also have a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). Please search the site before asking, or just check the [frequently asked questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent). Thank you.