# "The" before acronyms and abbreviations

Tags: articles, initialisms

I saw several posts about usage of "the" before acronyms, but I still haven't found any answer on my question. Let's say I developed a *System for Definitions' Retrieval* (SDR). So, should I refer to it as "the SDR" or just "SDR"?

The sentence is:

> Integration of *(the/a/?)* SDR database with lexical (synonyms, antonyms, etc.) databases.

Comment: I'd say _an SDR_.

Comment: Depends on context, **again**. It could be *an SDR* ("Let's say I developed an SDR") or *the SDR* ("Use the SDR I developed"). Please provide the actual sentence you are asking about.

Comment: If *you* develop the system, you get to call it whatever *you* are comfortable with. Just like you can call your company "The Microsoft" or "The Apple" if you so choose, and not just "Microsoft" or "Apple". On a broader note, since the name in question does not exist yet, it is impossible to tell what is proper and what is not, because what's proper and what's not is determined through usage, and the name hasn't been used yet.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms

Comment: @AndrewLeach That (comment) can be a generic solution to the problem at hand. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this contex, "SDR" appears in adjective context for "database", so the choice between *the/a* is strictly in classic context of "the database" or "a database" (depending on a broader context), and the acronym doesn't change a thing (except choice between a/an if that's what you pick; in this case the first letter of acronym is a vowel in pronunciation so *an es-...* ).

The situation would be different, if you abbreviated *System for Definitions' Retrieval Database* to *SDRD* - in that case you'd get to choose freely between *Integration of SDRD* and *Integration of the/an SDRD* (choice between *the* and *an* according to classic rules, if you integrate one random SDRD out of many, then *an*, if you pick a specific one, *the*)

Answer (score 1):

We call the British Broadcasting Corporation 'the BBC' but the National Broadcasting Company 'NBC'. If you invent a new way of piping, I suggest you can call the tune.

Comment: See here: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/initialisms-and-acronyms/

Comment: Yes; the article is wrong. 'But initialisms require _the_' is far from being a rule. I state above that 'NBC' is used instead of 'the NBC',  and you'll never hear a bald  'the ITV' in the UK. Also, 'laser' (an archetypal acronym) can be used as a count noun and be preceded by _a_ or _the_.

Comment: So, as a learner of English grammar I would ask, what is the rule?

Comment: There is sadly only one rule in English. Find out what accepted individual usages are. Here, the 'rule' given at your link will work pretty often, but what's the use of a 'rule' that lets you down unexpectedly? // In OP's example, as SF. says, the question doesn't arise. The initialism is a red herring; the question might as well be '[Should I use] "Integration of (the/a/?) new database ..."?'