# When using "an" before a vowel sounds wrong

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Consider the following sentence:
"This is a one-time deal" sounds right
"This is an one-time deal" sounds wrong

"One" is pronounced the same as "won", which wouldn't require an "an".

Is it proper/required to use the 'an' before a vowel rule when it just sounds wrong?

Comment: Please read [our blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) on the subject.

Comment: Matt- great post, did not realize it was purely a phonetic rule. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule that says you must use *an* before a vowel, only **before a word that begins with a vowel sound and takes the indefinite article**. *University* begins with a vowel but not a vowel sound, so it's always *a university*. The same is true for *a one-time deal*.