# When using "HR" for Human Resources, should "a" or "an" be used in front of it in a sentence?

Tags: abbreviations

IS HR an acronym?  Should "a" or "an" be used in front of it in a sentence, such as:
Do you have an HR question?

Comment: Simple answer: **Listen** to how you **say** "HR". Then [follow this rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111054/15299).

Comment: Use "those jerks in"...

Answer (score 5):

Since phonetically "H" begins with an "A" sound, one would use "an" instead of "a".
For example, FBI would also utilize "an" instead of "a" since "F" is an "Ef" sound. Since the acronym begins phonetically with a vowel, one needs to use "an", the article which preceeds regular words which begin with vowels.

Source: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/abbreviations.htm

Comment: Nice answer, I arrived at the same conclusion.