# Usage of 'an' with punctuation

Tags: grammar

I understand that you should use `an` if the following word begins with an `h`, however if there is some punctuation (such as a fullstop) in the next word, should it still be `an`?

> Do you have **an** .htaccess file?

or

> Do you have **a** .htaccess file?

Comment: How do you pronounce `.htaccess`? Do you say "dot" at the start? Do you say "huttaxess" (that is, without spelling the *ht* as individual letters)? The article depends solely on the pronunciation of what follows it.

Comment: You would prononounce it without the "dot", so "h t access". So then I can assume that it would be 'an'?

Comment: Yes. We actually have another question which is relevant: [Articles and acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Comment: Excellent, well that clears that up nicely! Thanks