# a ssl or an ssl?

Tags: pronunciation

I was talking about ssl somewhere, then I saw 'an ssl' was used on some other websites.
For example, https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/ But SSL word itself is not a vowel, so I thought it was 'a ssl'. What is the correct terms for this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the letters are pronounced or the term is expanded to "secure socket layer" or one uses some sort of coinage such as "sizzle".  As a computer geek I would say "ess ess el", and so "an" would be the proper article.  Remember, it's the vowel ***sound*** that triggers using "an" vs "a".

Comment: It was used as Secure Socket Layer.

Comment: @revi - Yes, but how is it *pronounced*?

Comment: As discussed here, this depends on the first sound, which is a vowel in this case: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms