# Completed "my" MSc or "an" MSC?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way of saying the following:

> 1. I have just completed my MSc in Psychology.

or

> 2. I have just completed an MSc in Psychology.

Thank you

Comment: The first one is correct. Second one shows an improper usage of vowels. You can only use "an" with vowels.

Comment: @John You're wrong, the letter M is pronounced "em" in this case you can use an "an". A/an is not related to which letter comes after but which sound.  for example, "a U-turn" not "an u-turn"    http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms

Comment: Good to know. I was aware of some other words like `hour` where `an` is used and few more but not with `M.Sc`. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both of those are grammatically correct, the difference between them is just what you want to emhasize.

If you say *I have just completed my MSc in Psychology*, then that will emphasize that it is *your* MSc and not someone else's. The sentence *I have just completed an MSc in Psychology* is more neutral, and does not focus on you. The latter could for example also mean that you completed an MSc thesis or diploma for somebody else.

The meaning of these sentences is also influenced by the context in which you say them, and of course which word you put emphasis on. In some contexts, they could mean the exact same thing.

Comment: "emphasize that it is your MSc and not someone else's". Who else's would you be completing?

Comment: @DJClayworth I know some guys who used to write other people's thesises for beers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that none of them is correct, but I found many similar sentences with google. Afaik. a degree is something you can get or earn, and *completing a degree* does not sound right. So I would say *I (have) just got my MSc (degree) in Psychology.* or *I (have) just finished an MSc program in Psychology*.

Answer (score 0):

I will share my reaction to the two choices, but replacing the letters with the word "masters" (because that sounds more natural to my ear).

> I just completed my masters in Psychology

sounds more formal than

> I just completed a masters in Psychology

If you were to use the first version in an informal situation, you would sound slightly pompous, but it would be forgivable.  That's my personal opinion.  (I speak U.S. English, by the way.)