# Is there an exceptional use of the article ‘a/an’?

Tags: grammar, articles

When I studied English, I learned that I have to use the article “a/an” in front of a noun whose first pronunciation starts with a vowel sound.

But whilst reading some texts, I realised that sometimes the article “a/an” is used in front of words that begin with “F”. How is this possible? I wonder if there is an exceptional case where I can use the article in front of other sounds than vowels.

Here are the sentences I found in the text
: “FTA+ is an FTA that in addition harmonizes some beyond the border standards.”

“An FC(Family Conglomerate)’s origins and growth often derive from a special relationship with the government.”

Plz share your knowledge with me :)