# What's the correct articulation for abbreviated words?

Tags: abbreviations, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

How to articulate abbreviated words when the original word articulation conflicts the pronunciation of the word?

For example, I would say

> A Facebook campaign for Donald Trump

But abbreviating `Facebook` to `FB` makes it difficult to keep the articulation intact

> A FB campaign for Donald Trump

or

> An FB campaign for Donald Trump

Which one is correct?

Second one seems easier to read

Comment: I'm not aware of any rule about it, but in speech I would go by the sound of the spoken letter (so, 'an FB').

Comment: In cases where the result is different I tend to choose the article to match how I say it or want it to be said.  If I want it read as "eff-bee" then I'll use "an"  if I want it to be read as "Facebook" I'll use "a".  Of course, if I really wanted it to be read as "Facebook" I'd just write "Facebook".

Comment: Questions very like this have been asked before; the consensus seems to be that it depends on how the abbreviation is pronounced: you write "an FB" if you'd spell it out when spoken (saying "an eff bee"). https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms

Comment: Yeah! that answers my question, thank you, should I flag this as a duplicate or delete it all together?

Comment: It's based on pronunciation. Do you say *an eff bee* or do you say *a fib*?