# Using 'a' or 'an' different in speaking and writing

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

There is an acronym- RPD.
In a ppt, made by my teacher for the students, there is a sentence-

> When the posterior abutment opposes the edentulous space or a RPD.

However as I speak this sentence I automatically use *an* RPD due to the sound of 'aar' for R.

So is it correct that a same sentence is written and spoken but one with 'a' and other with 'an'?
Or something is wrong, me or the ppt?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms

Comment: @KateBunting thank you. This answers my question