# Do you use a or an before acronyms / initialisms

Tags: indefinite-articles

**Whether to use ‘a’ or ‘an’ before acronyms/initialisms**

[Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms / initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms)

I think I understand the issues and principles as expressed by various contributors on this question.  But here’s an interesting one: is it equally correct to write ‘an SSSI’ and ‘a SSSI’?  The former would be articulated as ‘an es es es I’ and the latter ‘a triple S I’.

If the latter is equally acceptable are there any similar cases?

Thank you.

Comment: This _does_  answer your question: [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms / initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms) The accepted answer at the duplicate contains such an example: 'a FAQ' if treated as an acronym; 'an FAQ' if treated as an initialism. //// The a / an choice is determined **almost solely** on the basis of the following _sound_ (there is a grey area with a/an hotel, a/an historic, when the h-word is aspirated).

Answer (score 0):

The article is chosen based on the pronunciation of the first letter of the acronym. 'NASA' is pronounced as if if were a word, i.e. not N-A-S-A, so "A NASA official announced....." but NSA is pronounced as letters, and the letter N, when said aloud, started with a vowel sound, "en" therefore, "An NSA official was arrested today."