# What would be the correct article in this sentence?

Tags: articles

What would be the correct article to use in the following sentence?

> He proposed a ML-based parameter selection method

Should I use '*a*' or '*an*' ?

Comment: If you read it with its expansion, say machine learning, 'a' will precede it; if you read it as ML and pronounce so, the article is 'an'. An MP, an MLA; but a member of parliament.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms / initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms) See also [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an).

Comment: @niamulbengali, yes it answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you expect your reader to hear "em ell" or "machine learning" and that depends on which is normally said during conversations between people in your expected audience. The answer is probably "mixed," so it might be better to spell out the terms or consider just leaving the article out. Is it really necessary?