# "a" or "an" for words that don't start with vowels but sound like they're starting with a vowel

Tags: learning, indefinite-articles

Is it correct to say or write *an student* or *an store*?

Comment: How do you pronounce `st`? This doesn't feel natural.

Comment: I've noticed that speakers of Tagalog, for instance, seem to have difficulty saying words beginning with an S consonant blend, preferring to say estore or estudent.

Comment: moioci: There is at least one Filipino speaker who doesn't have that difficulty you speak of. :)

Comment: moioci: I believe people around the world also do that. Since there is no word starting with `s` followed by consonant in Portuguese, people tend to think and speak like `/ɪstɔːr/` instead of `/stɔːr/`

Comment: Ditto with Spanish.

Comment: Ditto with Hindi/Urdu speakers (i.e., they also tend to pronounce them istudent and iscore), but anyone with sufficient practice can cure themselves of this habit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Always use *an* for words which sound like they start with a vowel, and always use *a* for words which sound like they start with a consonant. The rules for *h* are more complex, and it can be ok to use either.

The usage of the indefinite article preceding *h* are [discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic). In particular, look at nohat's response.

As for *student* and *store*, they should always be preceded with *a* and never with *an*, because they both start with the consonant /s/ when spoken.

Correct:

> A student, a store

Incorrect:

> An student, an store

Comment: So e.g. A united states citizen, a unique opportunity but an uncle?

Comment: Yes. (extra text to fill limit)

Comment: Many Spaniards speaking English say "an (e)student"

Answer (score 8):

The quickest way to remember the rule for this: "an hour and a half". Thus, "a" for something with an initial consonant sound, and "an" otherwise.