# Is it "a SSD" or "an SSD"?

Tags: writing, terminology

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [an SQA or a SQA?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/an-sqa-or-a-sqa)
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Since SSD (solid-state drive) is pronounced es-es-dee, I'm wondering whether one should write "an SSD" or "a SSD".
Saying "a SSD" out loud feels a bit off...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [an SQA or a SQA?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/an-sqa-or-a-sqa), which is itself a duplicate of [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/)

Comment: See also: [“A historic...” or “An historic...”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/), [“a” or “an” for words that don't start with vowels but sound like they're starting with a vowel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/), [Use of “a” versus “an”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/), and [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/).

Comment: @RegDwight: Thanks. Since using a/an as a search term doesn't work very well, I didn't find a duplicate. Feel free to close as one.

Comment: Yes, the search is broken in that regard. Entirely not your fault. What I can recommend instead is having a look at the ["faq" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), or [googling using the "site:" operator](http://www.google.com/search?q=a+an+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Regarding the faq tab: I've been on Stack Exchange for about three months now, yet somehow I've never come across it before. Thanks a bunch for the suggestions! @RegDwight

Comment: "SSD" is pronounced /ɛs.../, and /ɛ/ is a vowel. So _an_ comes before a vowel. It's the way it's *pronounced*, not the way it's spelled. Forget spelling. Listen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely **an SSD.**

The use of *a* vs. *an* is always determined by pronunciation, not by spelling.  You don’t even need to find acronyms to give examples where they disagree: one would always say/write *a European*, not **an European*, and *an honest man*, not **a honest man*.

The only case where there’s doubt is when pronunciation varies.  For instance, with the acronym SCSI, computer professionals usually say “scuzzy”, but non-techies meeting it for the first time usually say “ess see ess eye”.  So one might reasonably encounter either *a SCSI cable* or *an SCSI cable*, depending on the writer.

However, as you say, SSD is (as far as I know!) always pronounced letter-by-letter; so it’s definitely *an SSD*.

Comment: Good to know.  I was taught it was by spelling, which can really be awkward!

Comment: Just because someone writes "SSD" doesn't mean they don't intend the reader to pronounce it "solid state drive" in which case you'd write "a SSD".

Answer (score 1):

The rule is actually about using an 'a' before a consonant *sound* and 'an' before a vowel *sound*. Now the rule is generalised to the one that you've stated, i.e. using 'a' before a word that starts with a consonant and 'an' before a word that starts with a vowel. 
The generalisation is true in most of the cases and this is precisely the reason why the rule is stated in its diluted form. 
But if we follow the rule we find that the exceptions vanish. SOA, as John has mentioned starts with an 'ES' sound which is a vowel sound. Hence the 'an'.

Read more [here](http://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/a-an.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Whether to choose "A" or "An" is an absolutely phonetic relationship.
It is not correct to say "A hour" even though its first letter is a consonant. It begins with a vowel sound, so you should say "An hour."

The same rule applies to abbreviations. The only case for not using "An" is if the reader is likely to say "Solid State Drive" instead of "Ess Ess Dee" even though you have not written it that way.

Current convention for your particular example indicates you should write "An SSD" based on this [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20ssd%2Can%20ssd&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20ssd%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20SSD%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20SSD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Can%20ssd%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20SSD%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAn%20SSD%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that if the word (in its **pronunciation**) starts with a vowel, you use "an". In other words, if the phonetic transcription of an English word begins with a vowel, you use "an". Examples: an orange (/o/), an apple (/æ/).

If it starts with a consonant, you use "a". Remember that /w/ and /j/ are considered consonants, which explains "a union" (/juːnjən/) and "a one-legged man" (/wən legd mæn/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent of the rule is the *sound* of the following word, not strictly if it begins with a consonant. I believe it is entirely dependent on pronunciation, not classification of the letter. Consider these two examples:

> He is **a** *solid* choice for class president.

...

> The next district superintendent is **an** *S. A.* Wilson High School graduate.

(The initials 'S' and 'A' are pronounced as the letters themselves.)

Here is some supporting information from the Purdue *Online Writing Lab*.
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/1/

Comment: This is not a question of belief.

Comment: Thanks @RegDwigнt, it was a statement of _my_ belief when I posted the initial answer. I was then driven to find the definitive answer, which I shared.