# "A" or "an" before abbreviation

Tags: indefinite-articles

Scenario: You're going to buy **a/an SSD**.

Do you use "a" or "an" before an abbreviation that is pronounced with a vowel first, but written with a consonant first?

When spoken, you would say "**an e**ss-ess-dee", but when written, should you use "**a S**SD" because there's actually a consonant as the next letter?

Comment: This exact question has been asked, and answered, before. The more general question has been asked, and answered, 50+ times. It is in the top 10 questions ever asked, and we even have a dedicated blog post. Please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/is-it-a-ssd-or-an-ssd) before asking.