# Writing a SOP or Writing an sop?

Tags: grammar

I know it should be "a" but it sounds so awkward? So should it be "an"?

Comment: An MOAQ on ELL (see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/is-it-a-ssd-or-an-ssd), for example; MOAQ = much often asked question). Also a duplicate of [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a before words that start with a consonant sound and an before words that start with a vowel sound. Other letters can also be pronounced either way. Just remember it is the sound that governs whether you use a or an, not the actual first letter of the word.

Answer (score 1):

[It is recommended that](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/04/using-a-or-an-with-acronyms-and-abbreviations.html), when dealing with abbreviations, you apply the "rule" based on how the abbreviation would be pronounced.  In this case, "Ess Oh Pee," requiring the article "an."