# Correct English: "An L.V." or "a L.V."?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, articles, abbreviations, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“a” or “an” for words that don't start with vowels but sound like they're starting with a vowel](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/a-or-an-for-words-that-dont-start-with-vowels-but-sound-like-theyre-startin)
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)
>   [Does one use 'a' or 'an' before the word X-Ray?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray)
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an/164)

I understand that "an" has to be used whenever the next word phonetically begins with a vowel. But in this case *L.V.* is an abbreviation.

Comment: an abbreviation that is pronounced is the same as a word in this context. This is no different from the other questions. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray

Comment: sorry for all the tag edits

Comment: I added british-english cause I had no idea what to tag it as. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read "L.V." as "el vee", therefore you need to precede it with "an".

> An el vee.