# Indefinite article confusion preceding "one-to-one"

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

While I was reading a book, I faced the following sentence:

> There is a one-to-one correspondence between the two sets of quantities.

So, my question is: why the indefinite article "a" is not "an" in this phrase? The following word starts with a vowel, so shouldn't it be "an"?

Comment: See http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/.

Comment: Also semi-relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question

Comment: You could solve your problem by saying *"bijective"* instead...

Answer (score 2):

The word ***one*** is pronounced as beginning with a /w/ sound.  Because this is a consonant sound and not a vowel sound, the indefinite article ***a*** is used instead of an.

Comment: People, this is such an obvious duplicate that you have no excuse for posting answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about spelling but about the pronunciation. 'one' is spelled with a vowel 'o' at the beginning, but it is the sound 'w' (a bilabial glide) that is not really a vowel.

Comment: People, this is such an obvious duplicate that you have no excuse for posting answers to it.

Comment: @Marthaª: I went to check the other answer first (I was going to immediately vote to close as duplicate), but I didn't see in the other question anything addressing this particular case. 'o' certainly looks like a vowel to most people (naively), so why doesn't the rule apply?

Comment: It's still the same rule: if it *sounds* like a consonant, use 'a'. We don't need to have separate questions about every letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @Marthaª: What about [“a” or “an” for words that don't start with vowels but sound like they're starting with a vowel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/)? That's a reasonable question if you don't know English and pronounce initial "st" as /est/. I see similar reasonableness with "one". It's a seeming exception to the rule that needs explanation.