# Why is ‘such an one’ obsolete?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles, archaicisms

*One* begins with a vowel and should therefore have *an* and not *a* in front of it. Why is it, then, that ‘such **a** one’ is what is actually said?

It appears to have been the case when the King James Bible was translated in 1611:

> 1 Corinthians 5:5
>
> To deliver such an one unto Satan for the destruction of the flesh, that the spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord Jesus.
>
> [(Bible Gateway)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+cor+5%3A5&version=KJV)

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+a+one%2Csuch+an+one&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=5&case_insensitive=true) reveal that ***such an one*** is not absent, although not as used as ***such a one***, in the publications of the 20th century.

Other questions like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an) or [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47933/indefinite-article-doubt-preceding-one-to-one) do not explain why *an* is obsolete. Was the pronunciation different before? What changed?

One hypothesis would be that earlier orthography was considered to stand above phonology. Is that the case?

Comment: Here is some research that shows it! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+one%2Can+one&year_start=1655&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20one%3B%2Cc0  Here is an exmaple:  “***Such an one who has the public administration, acts like the representative of his Maker.***"  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MEtO1630AikC&pg=PA179&dq=%22an+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBGoVChMI8rC9mp3vyAIVxj4UCh0wVwB0#v=onepage&q=%22an%20one%22&f=false

Comment: @Lawrence I've reworked the question for you into an ELU question. Questions should be complete and others should not need to do the work.

Comment: [*Descending from the Old English word an, “one” was the stressed form of what would become, in unstressed positions, the indefinite article a. Our modern pronunciation with the initial glide {wun} **did not appear until the eighteenth century**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22word+an+one+was+the+stressed%22)

Comment: ***An one*** vs ***a one*** :  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+one%2Can+one&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20one%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks for your useful link, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Following up on chasly's Ngram, which matches "a one" versus "an one," I ran an Ngram matching "such a one" versus "such an one"—[with interesting results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+a+one%2Csuch+an+one&year_start=1655&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3).

Comment: What strange way do you pronounce "one" that it begins with a vowel? Even variants like "yin" or "wan" start with a consonant.

Answer (score 8):

From [Inventing English: A Portable History of the Language](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J_YqCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT189&dq=%22word%20an%20one%20was%20the%20stressed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMItYG6nqvvyAIVx8MUCh32jwTD#v=onepage&q=%22word%20an%20one%20was%20the%20stressed%22&f=false) by Seth Lerer (2015)...

> *Other features of Shakespearean pronunciation include the pronunciation of the word **one**. Descending from the Old English word **an,** “one” was the stressed form of what would become, in unstressed positions, the indefinite article **a**. Our modern pronunciation with the initial glide [**wun**] did not appear until the eighteenth century.*<sup>1</sup>

---

A related issue discussed on [wordinfo.com](http://wordinfo.info/unit/3431/ip:1)...

> ***Occasionally** in modern writing and speech and regularly in the King James Version of the Bible, **an** is used before "h" in a **stressed** syllable, as in **an hundred.***

---

<sup>1</sup> [As commented by @Dan below...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284099/why-is-such-an-one-obsolete/284116?noredirect=1#comment1544660_284116)

> ***one** was usually pronounced like **own**, as it still is in compound words such as **alone** (all one), **atone** (at one),* and **only** ("one-ly").

Comment: It is interesting that he takes the phrase _an hundred_ as evidence that the _h_ was not pronounced. I wonder if that is right.

Comment: @Lawrence: Not sure who "he" means there. I've never heard anyone suggest the KJV use of ***an hundred*** relates to "cockney-style h-dropping". Nor is it anything to do with the still-current American usage ***an herb*** (which imho just reflects lah-di-dah French pronunciation long abandoned by Brits). Eventually only the "regular" rule relating to "initial vowel **sound**" will prevail, I'm sure. That *was* the rule for ***an one*** anyway; I think ***an hundred, an historic*** are down to something different, but I'm not too sure of the "etymology" on that front.

Comment: So how **was** *one* pronounced? "Own"? "On"? "Un"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the author of the book you quoted says: ‘It is clear, then, that in Shakespeare’s time[,] “hour” was pronounced without the initial _h_’, arguing from ‘a_n_ houre’.

Comment: Having seen fairly recent instances of the kind of usage in quæstion I am not entirely convinced by this answer, that it changed as a result of a phonetic change. Unfortunately I cannot recall exactly where those occurrences occurred.

Comment: @Andrew: I imagine it's likely that ***hour*** wasn't always aspirated, since the equivalent in French probably never was (most modern Francophones actually find it really *difficult* to emulate the English style). But ***hundred*** is a different story (it's essentially Germanic, where I don't think "unaspirated **h**" is really an issue). But I've no idea exactly how (or whether consistently) Chaucer's contemporaries, for example, differentiated ***a, an, one***.

Comment: @Lawrence: If you've seen *recent* instances, I suspect they'll be almost exclusively from nns. We're essentially talking about a *historical* usage here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, see edit. what is nns.; non-natives? no.

Comment: @Lawrence: Yeah, non-native speakers. Apart from a few "pathological" quirks (such as AmE ***an herb-port*** and pedantic BrE ***an [h]istoric occasion***), the *only* rule in play today is based on current pronunciation. If you see current instances of things like ***such an one*** they must be either nns or people deliberately emulating (or quoting) archaic sources. It hasn't survived in "standard" English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *one* was usually pronounced like *own*, as it still is in the compound words *alone* (all one) and *atone* (at one).

Comment: @Dan: Your excellent point is so well presented I couldn't resist copying it into my answer. If I ever was consciously of the "vestigial" nature of ***alone*** and ***atone*** pronunciation, I didn't remember it. But I don't think I'll forget it now. (At least, not until I'm well into my dotage! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You're welcome :)  And you can add ***only*** (one-ly) as another example.

Comment: @FumbleFingerss: I think that in the U.S., *an historic* very often **is** based on pronunciation. Many people in the U.S. drop the consonant "h" in unstressed syllables after words ending with "n" (and after some other consonants, as well). So *an 'istoric* is just as consistent a pronunciation as *a historic*. It's only some pedants that pronounce the "h" in *an historic* here. (Although I suspect that nearly everybody in the U.K. who uses *an historic* is one of these pedants, and that the *an 'istoric* pronunciation is nearly extinct there.)

Comment: @PeterShor: I first heard ***an historic occasion*** with aspirated /h/ from a "known to be competent speaker" ([Jeremy Paxman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Paxman), compering *University Challenge*) nearly 20 years ago. I've forgotten the tiresomely arcane details of why that *particular* one was "correct" when other similar collocations just apply the default rules for ***a / an.*** Paxman can be a bit of a show-off / pedant, but I certainly wouldn't want to argue with him! Maybe not in our lifetime, but I expect ***a historic*** will eventually be the only credible pronunciation.