# What's with the 'o' in 'one'?

Tags: pronunciation

Generally, *o*'s at the start of a word are either short (as in 'operation') or long (as in 'open'), or related sounds. However, the word 'one' has a very different initial sound, which (as far as I can tell, from playing around with *Mathematica*'s WordData constructs) is unique apart from related words like 'once', 'oneness' and 'oneself'.

How did this *o* come to be pronounced this way? Or, alternatively, how did this /wʌ/ come to be spelt with an *o*?

Comment: Relevant series of posts on the linguistics blog “Language Evolution”: [There Is Only Wun Such Number](http://langevo.blogspot.com/2013/02/there-is-only-wun-such-number.html) and the following posts, in particular [The Secret Ways of Weak Forms: Here Comes a New ’Un](http://langevo.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-secret-ways-of-weak-forms-here.html)

Comment: Related: [Why is ‘such an one’ obsolete?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284099)

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

It started in west and southwest England. According to the Online Etymology Dictionary,

> the now-standard pronunciation "wun" began c. 14c. in southwest and west England (Tyndale, a Gloucester man, spells it won in his Bible translation), and it began to be general 18c.

The word was originally meant to have a long o sound at the begining and you can still see this in the words atone and alone and an phrase/contractions such as good'un.

Comment: But good 'un doesn't have a long o. Could you add some etymology for "atone" and "alone?" That would be useful.

Comment: If this is purely about the sound, not the spelling then what does any of that say about either 'want' or 'wanton', please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin And while we're at it, what about "wont," which in the US is sometimes a homonym of "want." and sometimes pronounced with a long O, but seldom pronounced like won with a t attached, as I am wont to do..

Comment: Oh, yes. Many Brits also sound 'want' for 'wont' and never like 'won.'