# Should I use 'a' or 'an' when the following word is within parentheses?

Tags: grammar, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow now, and I'm unsure about this:

> I have ***an*** (Ruby on Rails site's) API which returns JSON data.

- 'API' starts with an 'A' so I should use 'an': `an API …`
- 'Ruby' (within parentheses) starts with an 'R' so I should use 'a': `a (Ruby …`

Must I use 'a' or 'an' in this case?

In other words, is the 'a' or 'an' only dependent on the following word **not** within parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is to reword things to move the parenthetical remark; it's not good to insert it at that particular point, because you're creating a dissonance between the stated indefinite pronoun "a", and the implied definite pronoun "the" that should apply because you're actually talking about a single specific API.

If you're using one of several possible APIs from the site:

> I have an API (from the Ruby on Rails site) which returns JSON data.

or if there's only one API from the site:

> I'm using the Ruby on Rails site's API, which returns JSON data.

Edit: Or if, as pointed out in the comments, it's from one of several possible RoR sites:

> I'm using a Ruby on Rails site's API, which returns JSON data.

or even better,

> I'm using this Ruby on Rails site's API, which returns JSON data

(and make "this Ruby on Rails site" a hyperlink)

Comment: Actually, it's **a** Ruby on Rails site's API. Not **the** Ruby on Rails site's API.