# Use "a" or "an" in a sentence with parentheses?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, articles, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

Should I use "a" or "an" in a sentence like this:

> There's just an (usually small, but) unbounded number...

or is it a bad style, anyway?