# How do you pronounce the H in "an historian"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

A lot of people I know argue that you should use the article "an" before words such as "historian", "history", "hotel", "hospital", "heretic".  I don't want to debate whether or not this is correct or merely pretentious affectation, but I'm curious about how it should be pronounced.

If I decide to use "an" before "historian", should I pronounce the H?  Should I say "an historian" or "an istorian"?

Comment: I... I don't understand. The article depends on the pronunciation of the word that follows. Not the other way round. You can't just decide to use "an" before "student" and then ask how it should be pronounced. I am very tempted to just close this as a dupe of [“A historic…” or “An historic…”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic)

Comment: @Reg "the article depends on the pronunciation of the noun" -- that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @RegDwight: OP isn't asking about a/an in general, just in the specific case of (certain?) words starting with **h**. And even Cerberus is a bit off-target, so this is obviously a tricksy little point. Luckily, kiamlaluno's quote from NOAD seems to cover it pretty well.

Comment: @lonesomeday: well, in that case, may I humbly direct your attention to [Use of “a” versus “an”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152/), easily found via the ["faq" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq) (not blaming you, even many regulars are not aware that it exists). Some special cases: [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/), [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/).

Comment: @Reg No need to do it humbly -- that's an excellent question to point to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: um, words starting with "h" in general, and words starting with "histor" in particular, are covered in the aforementioned [“A historic…” or “An historic…”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic). (^_^)

Comment: @RegDwight: Sorry. I don't know how I managed to miss the last sentence in your first comment. So far as I know the *only* vagueness in this whole area concerns words starting with enunciated "h". Which some (ultra-careful?) speakers precede by *an* if and only if the first syllable is unstressed. But some (wannabe-careful?) speakers ignore that 'stress test'.

Comment: Does this have any relation to "I sawr him," where I have occasionally heard an intrusive "r" before an enunciated "h"?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer: I assumed that hardly anybody would ever pronounce the h, mainly because I can't remember ever hearing it, and because it seems redundant. But I see you guys have more experience with this slippery h. I still think it would be best to advise people not to use it; does anyone feel it is a good idea to pronounce it after an?

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'd have thought the intrusive "r" there would be added *specifically* to get from sloppily-enunciated *saw* (with the "w" dropped) to *'im* (with the "h" dropped). No doubt there are speakers who add that "r" even when they enunciate the "h", but I'm not one of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'd have thought so too, but I have definitely heard it occasionally in the Boston area, where lots of people have non-rhotic speech and intrusive r's, but nobody drops h's. I'm puzzled, as well. It seems that, with "an" before historic and this Boston "sawr him/her", sometimes h's count as vowels for linking.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm a bit out of my depth on the Boston accent. Is it akin to UK 'Estuary English', in the sense of being characterised by what what many see as coarseness, carelessness, and laziness? So far as I'm concerned, obviously, accent is pretty irrelevant to judging either the speaker or what he says. As with the particular binding, paper quality, or typeface of a book, which gives no real clue as to whether it's worth reading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: JFK had an upper class Boston accent, but I'm not sure such a thing exists anymore ... upper class Bostonians now speak something much closer to general American, and I believe a Boston accent is now perceived as working class. Wikipedia gives a pretty good description of it. I'm curious about why an intrusive would appear before "h". It's certainly not my imagination: see for example [this link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/products.php?term=Boston%20Accent&defid=4035239), although the link does get it wrong in that an intrusive "r" would never appear in awesome.

Comment: I've figured out what's going on with "I sawr him." When I say "I told him", I barely pronounce the "h" (unless I'm emphasizing *him*) and I believe it's common in American speech to drop it completely. So even if the "h" is pronounced, if it's pronounced very faintly, an intrusive "r" makes sense.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Makes sense to me too. We're certainly prone to drop the 'h' in UK SouthEast too, which makes it pretty well obligatory to either enunciate the 'w' or add intrusive 'r'. Curiously, although enunciating the 'w' might seem to be more 'correct', if the 'h' *is* dropped, the 'r'-form somehow sounds less 'common'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Edited:]* My advice would be **not** to pronounce the *h* after *an*. This what I have always heard style books recommend.

I assumed that most people, if not all, who use *an* did not pronounce the *h*. I certainly can't remember ever hearing *h* pronounced after *an*; but it is always very dangerous to predict whether something is always or never the case. Wait, let me rephrase that: it is nearly always very dangerous... The main cause of this danger is that there will nearly always (see, I am learning) be exceptions. Even so, I believe they are exceptions; if someone disagrees and provides a decent argument or evidence, I will edit this answer again.

The use of *a* versus *an* in English is almost entirely based on whether the next word is pronounced as a vowel or not. The way it is spelled usually does not matter; compare *a user*, *an honour*. Based on this pattern, the advice of style books, and what I suspect is the pronunciation of a large majority, pronouncing the *h* with *an* seems like a bad idea. The fact that some people on this very page and elsewhere perceive it as "affected", and that it will displease traditionalists, would seem reason enough to drop either the *h* or *an*. A traditionalist might think, "hey, that guy is trying to sound cool, but he fails miserably, because he doesn't quite understand how it works", even if the speaker did in fact understand, but simply made a different choice. Such is snobbery.

Comment: You do sometimes hear *an hotel*, for example. Personally I think it's a bit of an affectation, but I'm pretty sure our UK news presenter Jermemy Paxman does it. And I surely would not wish to bandy words with *him* about whether he 'talks proper'.

Comment: If, as Cerberus notes, "The use of a v. an in English is purely based on whether the next word is pronounced as a vowel or not, nothing else", then what is all the talk of affectations and misuse. It stands to reason that these speakers are following the only rule English has to determine whether to choose a or an.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK, I assumed opinion on this was less divided, and practice more uniform, than it apparently is. I have changed my answer; do you think this is better? I still think it is a bad idea to pronounce the h after an, so I've kept that as the core of my answer.

Comment: @Cerebus: So long as Jeremy Paxman isn't reading this, I'm happy to say I agree absolutely with everything you say. If he *is*, I'd better dive for cover and admit that some careful speakers use *an* if the following word starts with an aspirated 'h' *and* the first syllable is unstressed. It grates on my ear, but the fact is they do it - justifiably, in their opinion. On reflection, I'm now pretty sure Paxman says "**a hotel**", but "**an historic**".

Comment: Worth pointing out that dropping the h on historic is an American English pronunciation. Regardless of whether you choose to use 'a' or 'an' in front of it, British English speakers pronounce the h (Oxford Dictionary). Dropping the h would mark your accent as either unrefined - for want of a better word ;) Alternatively, it could mark it as overrefined if you also peppered your speech with other 18th Centuryisms like 'weskit' for 'waistcoat'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Even Homer sometimes nods. We should be unforgiving of our own mistakes but laugh away those of others! I think nearly everyone is susceptible to snobbery in various ways, which is absolutely fine, as long as it stays within bounds and does not adversely affect others too much. (Some people just try to delude themselves that they are immune...)

Comment: @gpr: Fowler, Burchfield, and many others disagree: dropping the h in England is perfectly correct and respectable, but only in a very limited class of words, including *historical* and *habitual*. Outside this class of words, h dropping marks lesser refinement, as you say, except with certain unaccented words in fast speech, of which the details need not concern us now.

Comment: @Cerberus - I'm not sure those deceased gents are an accurate barometer of how English is *spoken* today. If Fowler were alive today, let's say he would be noted for his Victorian turn of phrase! 
On the other hand, the Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries both show the pronunciation of 'historic' with an h (Cambridge notes that the US pronunciation drops the h).

Comment: @gpr: Burchfield wrote this in 1997.

Comment: @Cerberus - Well I feel we could argue this for a while, but I'm sure Burchfield (who would have been 71 in 1997) had what to our ears would sound like a very posh manner of speaking. My tutors at Oxford were much younger than him, and they all sounded very posh to me.

Comment: @gpr: Ah, if you will grant that it is "respectable" in Burchfield's circles, we have no disagreement! I was just a bit surprised when you called it unrefined... "posh" isn't ungrammatical, is it?

Comment: @Cerberus - no, I only meant unrefined if you drop your aitches like a West Country farmer  (and maybe add them back in in the wrong places). If you drop your aitches like an 18th century dandy, you just sound posh.

Comment: @gpr: OK I can live with that!

Comment: Modern RP (the dialect I speak) sounds the "h" in historian, historical, history, habitual and so on. Some older forms did not. In my view saying "an historical" and pronouncing the "h" is an affectation.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: Well, in the views of others, it is not...and hello from the past!

Comment: @Cerberus - you might have to help me with "hello from the past". Perhaps contact me directly.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: This was unrelated to the content of your comment, but you replied to my 2011-self, so I replied back to you as a ghost from the past...you don't want to encounter a three-headed ghost in the dark alleys of SE!

Comment: @Francis: I believe you pronounce the *"h"* when you say *"the historian"*. But when you say *"this historian"*, do you pronounce the *"h"*? Many of us Americans don't (*"h"* in an unaccented syllable is dropped after consonants).

Comment: @PeterShor, really? That's never a speech pattern I've heard. I'll have to listen to Americans more carefully. What I'm complaining about is people who speak British English sounding the "h" in "an historian" and "an hotel" creating a really odd and unnatural feeling rule.

Comment: @Francis: I assume that this used to be the case in the U.K. as well, and that this was the origin of the rule: use *"an"* before an *"h"* in an unaccented syllable. But if people in the U.K. have stopped doing this, then saying *"an historical"* is definitely an affectation.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: Oh, wait, now I understand. I pronounce the h in  "Historians are..." at the beginning of a sentence, but I say "an istorian". I agree that pronouncing /nh/ there is odd, but then I doubt whether anyone does that. And I don't believe anyone ever dropped the h in "historian" at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: On the BBC one frequently hears "an historic" (with the "h" sounded). I'll keep an ear out for other RP variations.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: I have to agree, that sounds silly. I shall concentrate on the sound when next I listen to the BBC.

Answer (score 14):

The NOAD I had on my Mac Mini had a note similar to the following one, which *Oxford Living Dictionaries* reports about [*an*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/an) and its usage with words starting with *h*.

> Is it "a historical document" or "an historical document"? "A hotel" or "an hotel"?
>   There is still some divergence of opinion over which form of the indefinite article should be used before words that begin with *h* and have an unstressed first syllable. In the 18th and 19th centuries, people often did not pronounce the initial *h* for these words, and so an was commonly used. Today the *h* is pronounced, and so it is logical to use *a* rather than *an*. However, the indefinite article *an* is still encountered before the *h* in both British and American English, particularly with *historical*: in the Oxford English Corpus around a quarter of examples of *historical* are preceded with *an* rather than *a*.

The pronunciation reported by the *Oxford Living Dictionaries* for [*hotel*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hotel) is /hoʊˈtɛl/, and for [*historical*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/historical) is /hɪˈstɔrək(ə)l/; similarly, the pronunciation of [*historian*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/historian) is /hɪˈstɔriən/.

Answer (score 3):

**Usually not.**

For the most part, as Cerberus says, the use of *a* vs. *an* is based on whether the next word is pronounced with an initial consonant or not; so *an* would only be used when the *h* is pronounced.

However, the peculiar case of *an historic* etc. is one of those times when prescriptivism/snobbery/etc. has affected the language too much to be separable from “natural usage”.  I know many people whose accent would normally pronounce the *h* of *historic*, but who subscribe on more or less deliberately affected grounds to *an historic*, in writing and (less often) in speech.  From memory, I’m fairly sure I have heard it spoken sometimes as *an historic* with the *h* pronounced.

However, I can’t find to find audio/video evidence online to back this up.  The two examples of *an historic* I’ve found so far: [A US congressman](http://www.c-spanvideo.org/videoLibrary/clip.php?appid=596598244) (at about 06:46:50), who gives it no *h* that I can hear; and a [New Zealand librarian](http://www.linz.govt.nz/survey-titles/stats-projects-notices/paper-records-implementation/video-linz-moves-records/index.aspx) (at 00:24), who has no distinct *h* but has, I think, perceptibly more aspiration than after *an* than there would normally be for a following vowel.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that etymologically (or should I say, *historically*), *a* is a variant of *an*; not the other way round. In other words, [the *n* disappeared before consonants](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a), rather than being added before vowels.

Comment: Okay, I have adjusted my assumption that hardly anyone would ever pronounce the h with an. But my advice still remains "don't do it"... if your advice is "usually not", do you suppose it would be a good idea to do it in a group where everybody's doing it, or something like that? I guess peer pressure can be a good enough reason to do things you otherwise wouldn't do, hehe...

Comment: Whenever I hear "an historic" (or the like, and I should note it is only on television, usually the BBC), the 'h' is not silent.

Comment: One frequently hears it on BBC Radio 4. "An historic" being an example.

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be people who say *"an historian"*, pronouncing both the *"n"* and the *"h"*, in the U.K. I don't think this is the case with most American speakers who use *"an"* with *"historian"*. Let me explain what I think is going on.

In my speech (a variety of American English), an /h/ in an unaccented syllable following a consonant is either not pronounced or absorbed into the consonant, so the consonant becomes slightly more aspirated. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28939/why-does-is-replace-has). So in *"their historical building"* the /r/ and the /h/ merge together to form a slightly breathier /r/. And after most consonants, the /h/ vanishes entirely. This wouldn't happen with *"their histories"*, where the /h/ is in an accented syllable and thus pronounced.

You can see that both *"an istorian"* and *"a historian"* are consistent with this system for pronouncing /h/. Which one a speaker says is probably a matter of what they heard when they were learning English. Most speakers of American English use *"a"* with *"historian"*, but there is a minority that uses *"an"*. Speakers who use *"an"* would say /hɪˈstɔriən/ after a vowel, but say /ənɪˈstɔriən/, either without the /h/ or with a very faint /h/. The same speakers would also drop the /h/ in the sentence *"I find historians interesting."*

As some evidence that this is really what is going on, I recently heard within the space of two or three minutes the same speaker of American English say *"a historical"* /əhɪˈstɔrɪkl/ with the *"h"* and  *"an istorical"* /ənɪˈstɔrikl/ without it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit like asking "what is the correct pronunciation of 'an biscuit'?". You're asking for the 'correct' pronunciation of a form which is essentially ungrammatical (probably).

In 2011, there's probably no "real" natural pronunciation of "an historic". The form probably only occurs as a hypercorrection by people who have seen such forms written down from a previous stage of the language. At one time, the "h" of various words (including "history", "hotel") behaved essentially as in the "h" or "heir" and "hour". Nowadays, they basically don't; the usual, naturally occurring form is "a history", "a historic event", "a hotel" etc. 200 years ago, pronouncing "an 'istoric" rather than "a historic" was probably as natural as saying "a biscuit" rather than "an biscuit" today. But this is no longer the case.

However, a few speakers do in writing ape the previous usage, and this then leads to the "problem" of how to pronounce a form that essantially "doesn't occur" naturally. In practice you will often hear speakers pronounce the "h". As I say, I think the form per se is essentially a hypercorrection, so to ask whether you "should" pronounce the "h" seems to me a meaningless question.