# "I wrote a (albeit very rough) draft" or "I wrote an (albeit very rough) draft"

Tags: indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“a/an” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

Does the parenthetical phrase change the "a" to an "an"?

If you remove the parenthetical phrase, then you'd obviously be saying "I wrote an draft" which is incorrect...

Comment: I am not sure that "albeit" can be so easily parenthesized - see usage http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/albeit?view=uk