# How to properly use brackets and articles when the article is changed by the bracketed word?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A/An” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

I was just posting a question on another Stack Exchange website. And I ran into the following sentence:

> How do I safely reinstall a (audio) driver?

What should the article be, *a* or *an*? Should I use brackets to get *a(n)*?