# "An (sweet) apple"?

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A/An” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

is the correct form

```
A (sweet) apple
```

because the article "A" precedes the word sweet, although it is put in brackets (as a side remark), or is the correct form

```
An (sweet) apple
```

because the effect of "sweet" on the form of the article has been nullified by the brackets?

One might argue this depends on whether I regard the word within the bracket to be pronounced when the text is read aloud.