# Using correct indefinite article before (in-line) parentheses

Tags: articles, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A/An” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

This is rather question of readability:

Which article should be preferred?

> There is an (seemingly) easy correction to this issue.

favoring "an easy" or

> There is a (seemingly) easy correction to this issue.

if you hear "a seemingly easy".

Comment: Spell it as you'd say it: *There is a (seemingly) easy correction to this issue.*

Comment: We have an excellent [blog article](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) that explains this in the section about parenthetical statements.