# "a" vs. "an" when the following word is in a bracket

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A/An” preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement)

Let's say I send a text to someone saying:

> Can you get me a coffee?

Over here, I use *a* as the following word doesn't begin with a vowel, which is all very good.

Now what if the person got me a bad coffee (like decaf or something). So I send another text:

> Can you get me  (actual) coffee?

Now what would I use? *a* or *an*? As *actual* is in brackets, does it enforce the rule of requiring *a* to become *an*?