# The use of indefinite article next to a parenthetical

Tags: indefinite-articles

### Context

Trevor was intrigued by the problem associated with the use of the indefinite article `a`. The two versions of the sentence that sparked this reaction are as follows:

Version Gamma:

> The tragic element is this: it should not require an (ostensibly fairly
>   rare and not-trivial-to-obtain) external substance to make such a
>   thing an every-day reality.

Version Epsilon:

> The tragic element is this: it should not require a ( fairly
>   rare and not-trivial-to-obtain) external substance to make such a
>   thing an every-day reality.

### Questions

- 1) Is version Epsilon grammatically correct?
- 2) What is the technical nomenclature for the problem that occurs between `ostensibly` and `fairly` relative to their position to the indefinite article?

Comment: Oh alpha and beta, we hardly knew ye.

Comment: I thought that for every epsilon, there exists a delta.

Comment: 1) No. What you have is an aside. _It is not part of the sentence_ and therefore does not affect anything. 2) I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: The first part is addressed by this question: [“A/An” preceding a parenthetical statement](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368)