# A/An question: 'a humanitarian' or 'an humanitarian'?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” versus “an” in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)

What's the proper wording here, neither one sounds right to me:

> "[Chevra](http://chevrahumanitarian.org/), **an** humanitarian
>   organization..."

or

> "[Chevra](http://chevrahumanitarian.org/), **a** humanitarian
>   organization..."

My instinct says it follows the same rule as "an hour", but the 'h' sound is more pronounced in 'humanitarian', so I'm unsure.

Comment: if a vegetarian eats vegetables, what does a humanitarian eat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your accent, because the "a/an" pattern is completely phonological.  Some dialects don't pronounce the [h] very strongly or at all in cases where it is followed by [j] (the "y" sound), like in "humanitarian" [hjumæn...], "humor", or "huge".  In my dialect, the [h] is definitely pronounced so I would write "a", and I believe this is the most common pronunciation in the US (though I am not certain).

Comment: But even if someone drops the /h/, wouldn't they use "a" because /j/ is a consonant? We don't say "an universe" (or at least, not in modern English), and that starts the same as ’umanitarian.

Comment: @suməlic: Yes. I have no idea what I was thinking back then. The part about [h] pronunciation is true but it has no impact on a/an.