# Why is 'an' used with 'an honour'?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, indefinite-articles, phonology, vowels

Why is 'an' used with 'an honour'? Isn't 'an' limited to the vowels?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic

Comment: possible duplicate of ["A user" or "an user"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/a-user-or-an-user)

Comment: "honour" starts with a vowel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the 'h' is silent in *honour* (or, in America, *honor*).

Sometimes 'an' is used even if the 'h' is aspirated, as in "This was an historic occasion."

Comment: But that's because it is pronounced "an 'istoric occasion at an 'otel", but "the historic hotel" has fully aspirated h's; English is weird!  You also, of course, get "an umbrella" but "a ukelele".

Comment: @Jonathan: I frequently hear people say "an historic occasion" with no elision of the "h".

Comment: I can't help it if they weren't brought up to speak proper, can I?  :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "An umbrella" vs. "a ukelele" isn't weird. *Ukelele* starts with a consonant sound (a *y* glide).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you have any idea in what areas "an 'istoric" is the common pronunciation?  Where I live (Austin, TX) I'm pretty sure most people would say "a historic".

Comment: and @JonathanLeffler that's speak proper*ly* ;)

Comment: @Andy: I'd suggest some parts of southern England would use "an 'istoric" with no or almost no aspiration on the h.  For example, I'm fairly sure that's what I'd say.  And the 'proper' vs 'properly' is intended to be a joke in some English dialect — Cockney or thereabouts.  It's more than a tad difficult to convey that in a comment on SO, though..  I suppose I could have shown some glottlestops (or is that "glo'lestops"?) etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler gotcha, I wasn't sure :)

Answer (score 11):

As I understand it, an 'An' should be used before words that *sound like* they start with a vowel.

This can lead to ambiguity like 'SQL database'. This could either be written as 'an SQL database' or 'a SQL database' depending upon whether you pronounce SQL as 'S-Q-L' or 'sequel'.

Comment: Good point, I never think of it as Sequel and so always use AN

Comment: A vowel is, first and foremost, a sound. The "a"/"an" rule is a rule based on sound.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is very helpful as well.