# "A user" or "an user"?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)
>   [“A” becomes “an” before a word beginning with a vowel, does this apply to “u”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/a-becomes-an-before-a-word-beginning-with-a-vowel-does-this-apply-to-u)
>   [Is it “a uniform” or “an uniform”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/is-it-a-uniform-or-an-uniform)
>   [Which is correct — “A Year” or “An Year”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/which-is-correct-a-year-or-an-year)

I noticed an ad on Stack Overflow featuring another StackExchange site and the title of the question had this in it:

> Allow an user to...

But shouldn't it be

> Allow a user to...

Am I wrong or is this just one of those exceptions?