# What is the rule for using "a" or "an" in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“A user” or “an user”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/a-user-or-an-user)
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)

If I remember correctly back to my school days, the rule is to use "a" if the next word starts with a consonant, or "an" if the next word is a vowel.

For example:

- This is *a* banana.
- This is *an* egg.

If the above is correct, then why does this sentence sound wrong...?

- The account requires *an* username.

Comment: I tried to add a consonant tag, but their isn't one and I don't have enough rep!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [A user or AN user](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/a-user-or-an-user),[Use of A versus AN](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an), [When to correctly use AN and A](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19893/when-to-correctly-use-an-and-a) Read the first question I linked, it's the exact duplicate of yours. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I searched the site for keywords A and AN, but it didn't return anything!! Not sure why, but thanks for the link.

Comment: the site search doesn't really work for such short and general words. Entirely not your fault. What I can recommend instead is having a look at the ["faq" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq) (where 3 out of the top 5 questions deal with *a* vs *an*), or [googling using the "site:" operator](http://www.google.com/search?q=a+an+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a word begins with a *u*, sometimes it a acquires what linguists call a "y-glide": a pronunciation that makes it sound like it begins with a "y":

- user (yoozer)
- uniform (yooniform)
- ubiquitous (yoobiquitous)

And so on.

Now think of words you pronounce that begin with "y": a youth, a yew — you wouldn't say "an youth" or "an yew".

So we say "a user" but "an understanding" — just that simple.