# What are correct words to use in order to name a user that updates something?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

I would like to find correct words to use in order to name a user that updates something. That is, if for a user that creates something I say "creator user", what may I say for a user that updates something?

For example, is "updater user" correct?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether by 'user creator' you mean 'one who creates users' or if you simply mean 'a user who creates <anything creatable>'.  The term 'user creator' definitely implies 'one who creates users'.

Comment: @Jim - Maybe I was wrong. I updated the question (in particular, from `user creator` to `creator user`).

Comment: @Jim - You are welcome. ; - )

Comment: It's *a user*. Not *an user*. (Since you have made the mistake not once but four times I assume it wasn't just a typo.) The article is decided by the pronunciation of the following word. We have three dozen questions on that, including one [specifically about the word *user*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/a-user-or-an-user), and even a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/).

Comment: @RegDwight ΒВBẞ8 - You are right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the word 'updater' for your application as others suggested.

I tried to find the word 'updater' but it doesn't exist in any dictionary yet. However, it was used at several places in computer related stuff. I can't think of a word that would describe the job of this person but I'm sure 'modifier' doesn't fit perfectly, or does it?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the application is, but for something like text or content you could use "editor".

Answer (score 2):

*Editor* is probably good enough, but you might also consider *contributor* or *collaborator*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how sophisticated your program is, but I typically will use *roles* for this. I.e., define a *creator* role, an *updater* (or editor) role, etc.  This might be all rolled into an 'admin' role if that fits your use cases.  In any case you can then talk about '*users with the < fill-in-the-blank> role.*'

Answer (score 0):

"the man who updates" may be a better choice.

For example:

I become the man who updates blogs.

Comment: This seems like an overly verbose construction, some people might call it sexist too.

Answer (score -2):

*Updater* is alright, although *editor* might be an alternative.

I'm wondering why you use "creator user" and "updater user" though: why not just "creator" and "updater"? Surely a creator and updater can only be users, or they wouldn't be creating or updating? Is the word "user" really necessary?

Comment: Those words are technical. However, I updated the question as said in response to the Jim comment.