# "A" or "an" with words beginning with the letter H

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A historic…” or “An historic…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic)

I am wondering when it's correct to use *a/an* with words beginning with the letter *h*. For example:

*an historian*, *a history*.

I remember reading somewhere that the *h* is sometimes silent, in which case it's *an*, and when the *h* is pronounced, it's *a*. But then I also remember reading that it depends on which syllable is stressed. And I also think I read somewhere that it might differ between British and American English.

So how do I know when to use *a* and when to use *an* with a word beginning with the letter *h*?