# Correct pronunciation of "herbs"

Tags: pronunciation

In the past, I used to say "Herbs", then I was corrected and told that the "H" is muted and one should say "Erbs". Watching some video, the instructor keeps saying "Herbs". What is the right pronunciation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pronounced both ways. NOAD gives this:

> **herb** |(h)ərb|

The parenthetical *h* indicates that it may be aspirated or omitted.

Comment: Somehow people believe statistics, but popularity doesn't necessarily mean it's right

Comment: @Third Idiot: the established pronunciations in both the U.S. and the U.K. (these are different) are prevalent enough that most people would insist that the other pronunciation is incorrect. So no /h/ is correct in the U.S. and with /h/ is correct in England.

Comment: No /h/ is *definitely* the way to do it in Jamaica. :)

Comment: The comedian Eddie Izzard has [something to say about this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cs5H7cgcpkg); I believe that's become one of his more iconic lines.

Comment: "Language" Sketch from "Dressed to Kill" by Eddie Izzard, the link posted by J.R. above is "dead". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXBHY7uco0Y

Answer (score 22):

The American pronuncation is usually /ərb/ without the h, while the British pronunciation is usually /hɜː(r)b/ with the h, but maybe without the r.  It was formerly pronounced without the h in the U.K; the British author E. Nesbit used "an herb" in her book *The Wonderful Garden* (1911), probably indicating that she pronounced it without the h.

Comment: The American pronunciation of *herb-* in combining forms varies. From Google Ngrams, the *American Heritage Dictionary,* and my gut feeling, I would say that you should not pronounce the 'h' in *herbage* and *herbal,*  but that it's usually pronounced in *herbarium,* *herbicide,* *herbivore,* and *herbaceous.*

Comment: Shor, I would pronounce the h in none of your example words, and generally would be surprised to hear any American English speaker say those words with an h, American dictionaries’ pronunciation guides notwithstanding.

Comment: @nohat: Compare the frequencies of "a herbal tea", "an herbal tea", "a herbicide" and "an herbicide" in [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+herbal+tea%2Can+herbal+tea%2Ca+herbicide%2C+an+herbicide&year_start=1800&year_end=2006&corpus=5&smoothing=3) for American English. Certainly "an herbicide" is not uncommon enough to be called incorrect, but "a herbicide" is more frequent.

Comment: Putting it another way, if you pronounce the 'h' in *'herb', 'herbal',* and *'herbage',* most Americans will be convinced that you're wrong. For *'herbicde', 'herbivore',* etc., there are lots of Americans who pronounce it each way.

Comment: @shor
The use of the article 'an' before a word beginning with 'h' does not guarantee that 'h' is silent. I remember to have seen on more than one occasion the use of 'an hotel' in older British books, one of them being 'Just William' by Richmal Crompton.

Comment: It [does](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h) for one-syllable words.

Comment: All this time and nobody has suggested "oibz". I'm proud of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right pronunciation?

That depends on which English, you speak. It is one of the many differences American English has from British forms of English. The h is not pronounced by Americans. It is pronounced by English (and other British) people. This page http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/herb?q=herb , demonstrates it.