# Attention Americans: Do you use the SILENT H in the beginning?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

English *is* my mother tongue and we often follow the British pronunciations.

However, something caught my attention recently. In my Oxford dictionary, I noticed that so many words that begin with 'wh' have a leading 'h' as part of the phonetics. Here are some of them:

> what
>
> when
>
> wheeze
>
> wheel
>
> wheat
>
> whatever
>
> whip

and the list goes on...

I have heard many US accents but never encountered this. Perhaps I never noticed it.

Thus my question: Do Americans really use these words with a leading `h` or at least are they supposed to?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am not using the net as my source here. It's a printed book. So for those who are unsure, here it is:

[image]

BTW, the exact title of the dictionary is:

Oxford WordPower

English-Arabic dictionary

ISBN: 0-19-431485-5

NEWEST EDIT: Please do not consider this a duplicate of [Hwat, hwere, and hwy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84177/hwat-hwere-and-hwy)

That discusses the origins of words and various 'accents'. Yes, the examples are related, but my question is different and simple. I'm more keen on knowing if *Americans (today) use the leading h pronunciation (at large)?*

Ever since I started my study of languages (my mother tongue included), I've tried to stick to a standard pronunciation from the dictionary. Thus in a way I look at the dictionary's pronunciation as the *right* way to pronounce words, regardless of what people really do. So now after seeing the leading h pronunciation related to Americans, I'm curious to know if they really do so.

And after the kind of responses and links I've seen on this subject today, I don't even think that an average non-academic American really knows this exists. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/what?q=what   /wɒt/

Comment: It’s apparently the norm in the south of the United States and in Scotland, amongst other places. We have questions of this.

Comment: @TaliaFord Please go down the page on the link you gave me. You'll see what I mean. And then there's the other link on that page here: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/what That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Most Americans don't do it, but some do. However (like many Americans who don't even hear the difference between *merry* and *Mary*), you may not even notice the difference between /hw/ and /w/ if you aren't listening for it.

Comment: I think some of the posher British accents do that too.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not sure if my mind is playing games but I think it's kind of easier to use the /hw/ method for pronouncing, especially when tired :)

Comment: Perhaps a language expert from the US should pronounce these words with and without the leading h and make a video on youtube - smiles

Comment: Oh wow I totally didn't know. I heard once a while back this geezer from Georgia speak like that but I thought he had a lisp or something. He was just weird all around... and about 80.

Comment: Relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25410/25030

Comment: The original PIE interrogative/relative words had _*kʷ-_, still preserved in Latin QU-; _qui, quae, quod, qualis, quantus_, etc. PIE _*kʷ-_ changed to _xʷ_ in Germanic via Grimm's Law. In most Modern English dialects the distinction between /hʷ/ and /w/ has been lost. Mine, for instance (Midwestern USA, b 1942 DeKalb Co IL, right on the Northern/Midlands isogloss bundle).

Comment: This is a superb collection of points. Please, somebody, put them into one answer and polish it up if possible.

Comment: I wonder if any accents do not aspirate the _h_ in words like _whore_ or _who_. Also, [this article](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/pronouncing-words-that-begin-with-wh/) has some nice examples.

Comment: @terdon That link to the article is cool. But the comments are awesome :)

Comment: Your question is answered in the duplicate question: it's pronounced in **"many parts of North America, especially but not only the south of the United States."**.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_wh#Wine.E2.80.93whine_merger), which has a map of the region of the South where "wh" is still used by a majority of speakers.

Comment: Obligitory: http://youtu.be/B1Vcbm-XWtg. Everyone I know ignores the 'h', American or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some do!  Some don't.  I said these words to myself just now to see what I do, and wouldn't you know it, I do put a teensy tiny "h" in front of these.  Kind of like "hWat?"  It's barely discernable, even to me.

Amazing to learn after all these years that I pronounce some words in a way I would never have imagined.  Wow!  Or is that hWow?

I'm originally from Southern California, and probably had an original "O.C" accent, but since age 15 I've been all over: Toronto, Canada; Cheltenham, England; Germany for 3 years and Yes I speak it fairly fluently; Washington state, USA, for the past 30 years.  My accent is probably so muddled up by now there's no way to tell what I sound like.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wish to remind that the letter "H" is more acceptably pronounced "age" or "eij" not "heige"/"heij".

There, the pronunciation of "H" itself does not involve the sound of "H. I've been to parts of Asia and US where they pronounced it "heige" - somewhat coincident in places where they also pronounce "pronounciation" rather than "pronunciation".

The way I've been brought up, which may not agree with others

- Elision of h to before w to emphasize the presence of an "h". Therefore we pronounce "hwen", "hwat",etc.
- In the US, people pronounce "herb" as "erb", "homage" as "omage"/"ormarj". I think the Queen of England would not coincide with such pronunciation. Neither does the Oxford dict. I am more comfortable pronouncing them with the non-silent "H". I think US pronunciation standardization efforts are simply too zealous.
- Regardless of dialect, the "H" mostly becomes silent when paired with a prior word that ends with a consonant:
  green herb = green'erb
- However, if the prior word ends with "T", I would encourage people to pronounce "herb" rather than "erb". e.g, "fragrant herb" rather than "fragrant 'erb". Could be misheard as "fragrant turd".
- Regardless of dialect, the elided "H" in "when", "where", etc, is not silent, even when paired with a prior word ending with a consonant. e.g.

  - he says hwen
  - tell him hwere

Comment: I beg to differ, I would never pronounce _when_ or _where_ with an audible _H_, irrespective of the previous word. I always pronounce them using the same sound as for _wish_.

Comment: So what you're saying is that although it's technically correct to use the leading h, it's a matter of choice despite the dictionary's rule of pronunciation. I like that :)

Comment: I am an American, and I pronounce *whales* and *Wales*, *which* and *witch*, *when* and *win*, exactly the same, independent of what (if any) consonant the prior word ends in. I don't have the faintest idea of what you mean by "the elided 'H' ... is not silent". ***It is for me.***